# What does `=>` do in Mozilla's JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

In Mozilla's [sample code for Downloads.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#Observing_downloads) there's a few lines that use `=>` which I don't know the meaning of:

```
let view = {
  onDownloadAdded: download => console.log("Added", download),
  onDownloadChanged: download => console.log("Changed", download),
  onDownloadRemoved: download => console.log("Removed", download),
};
```

What does `=>` do here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of “=>” in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the syntax of upcoming version of JavaSctipt, the ECMAScript 6, aka Harmony.

The `x => expr` syntax stands, more or less (with differences with treatment of `this`), for `function (x) { return expr; }`.

Answer (score 3):

They're a special function literal notation, called [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions), introduced with ES6. It's basically the same as in coffeescript.

It could have been shorter written as `console.bind(console, "Added")` :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is called "arrow functions" or "lambda expressions".

If you want to use that and not wait for ECMAScript 6, you can have a look at [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) , you don't have to worry about browser compatibility and this kind of stuff.

You can check [an example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20calc%20=%20x%20=%3E%20x%20+%201;%0A%0Aalert%28calc%281%29%20==%202%29;).