# What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I know that the `>=` operator means more than or equal to, but I've seen `=>` in some source code. What's the meaning of that operator?

Here's the code:

```js
promiseTargetFile(fpParams, aSkipPrompt, relatedURI).then(aDialogAccepted => {
    if (!aDialogAccepted)
        return;

    saveAsType = fpParams.saveAsType;
    file = fpParams.file;

    continueSave();
}).then(null, Components.utils.reportError);
```

Comment: See this link about the [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 621, accepted):

## What It Is

**This is an arrow function.** Arrow functions are a short syntax, introduced by ECMAscript 6, that can be used similarly to the way you would use function expressions. In other words, you can often use them in place of expressions like `function (foo) {...}`. But they have some important differences. For example, they do not bind their own values of `this` (see below for discussion).

Arrow functions are part of the ECMAscript 6 specification. They are not yet supported in all browsers, but they are partially or fully supported [in Node v. 4.0+](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and in most modern browsers in use as of 2018. (I’ve included a partial list of supporting browsers below).

[You can read more in **the Mozilla documentation** on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions).

From the Mozilla documentation:

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and lexically binds the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value (does not bind its own [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)). Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions and they can not be used as constructors.

### A Note on How `this` Works in Arrow Functions

One of the most handy features of an arrow function is buried in the text above:

> An arrow function... lexically binds the `this` value (does not bind its own `this`...)

What this means in simpler terms is that the arrow function retains the `this` value from its context and does not have its own `this`. A traditional function *may* bind its own `this` value, depending on how it is defined and called. This can require lots of gymnastics like `self = this;`, etc., to access or manipulate `this` from one function inside another function. For more info on this topic, see [the explanation and examples in the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this).

## Example Code

Example (also from the docs):

```
var a = [
  "We're up all night 'til the sun",
  "We're up all night to get some",
  "We're up all night for good fun",
  "We're up all night to get lucky"
];

// These two assignments are equivalent:

// Old-school:
var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

// ECMAscript 6 using arrow functions
var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );

// both a2 and a3 will be equal to [31, 30, 31, 31]
```

---

## Notes on Compatibility

You can use arrow functions in Node, but browser support is spotty.

Browser support for this functionality has improved quite a bit, but it still is not widespread enough for most browser-based usages. As of December 12, 2017, it is supported in current versions of:

- Chrome (v. 45+)
- Firefox (v. 22+)
- Edge (v. 12+)
- Opera (v. 32+)
- Android Browser (v. 47+)
- Opera Mobile (v. 33+)
- Chrome for Android (v. 47+)
- Firefox for Android (v. 44+)
- Safari (v. 10+)
- iOS Safari (v. 10.2+)
- Samsung Internet (v. 5+)
- Baidu Browser (v. 7.12+)

Not supported in:

- IE (through v. 11)
- Opera Mini (through v. 8.0)
- Blackberry Browser (through v. 10)
- IE Mobile (through v. 11)
- UC Browser for Android (through v. 11.4)
- QQ (through v. 1.2)

You can find more (and more current) information at [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) (no affiliation).

Comment: TypeScript also seems to support it.

Comment: It looks like this is a lambda expression, yes?

Comment: Wanted to mention in terms of browser compatibility I use ES6/ES7 arrow functions and other features not compatible with IE11 natively but I use Gulp or Webpack along with Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5 so it works in IE11. So if you need IE11 support and you don't mind setting up Babel then go for it.

Comment: [Today they're supported in all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions).

Comment: @DonaldDuck True, but that page also shows that not all users are using modern browsers. About 96.2% of users are on a browser that supports arrow functions, but that isn't 100%. Depending on the context, that 3.8% may or may not be a good reason to avoid a given language feature. (Don't get me wrong; personally, I'd say that's close enough and covers all legit users. But YMMV.)

Answer (score 88):

That's known as an Arrow Function, part of the [ECMAScript 2015 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions)...

```js
var foo = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'];

var bar = foo.map(f => f.length);

console.log(bar); // 1,2,3
```

Shorter syntax than the previous:

```js
// < ES6:
var foo = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'];

var bar = foo.map(function(f) {
  return f.length;
});
console.log(bar); // 1,2,3
```

**[DEMO](http://www.es6fiddle.net/hxy1g4ey/)**

The other awesome thing is *lexical* `this`... Usually, you'd do something like:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.name = name;
  this.count = 0;
  this.startCounting();
}

Foo.prototype.startCounting = function() {
  var self = this;
  setInterval(function() {
    // this is the Window, not Foo {}, as you might expect
    console.log(this); // [object Window]
    // that's why we reassign this to self before setInterval()
    console.log(self.count);
    self.count++;
  }, 1000)
}

new Foo();
```

But that could be rewritten with the arrow like this:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.name = name;
  this.count = 0;
  this.startCounting();
}

Foo.prototype.startCounting = function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(this); // [object Object]
    console.log(this.count); // 1, 2, 3
    this.count++;
  }, 1000)
}

new Foo();
```

**[DEMO](http://www.es6fiddle.net/hxy2anuu/)**

*[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions)*
*[More on Syntax](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:arrow_function_syntax)*

For more, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6) a pretty good answer for *when* to use arrow functions.

Comment: It would be good to update the demos to use https://esfiddle.net/ as https://es6fiddle.net/ is no longer operational

Answer (score 29):

## These are Arrow Functions

Also known as **Fat Arrow Functions**. They're a clean and consise way to write function expressions, e.g. `function() {}`.

Arrow Functions can remove the need of `function`, `return` and `{}` when defining functions. They are one-liners, similar to Lambda Expressions in Java or Python.

### Example with no parameters

```js
const queue = ['Dave', 'Sarah', 'Sharon'];
const nextCustomer = () => queue[0];

console.log(nextCustomer()); // 'Dave'
```

If multiple statements need to be made within the same Arrow Function, you need to wrap, in this example, `queue[0]` in curley brackets `{}`. In this case the return statement cannot be omitted.

### Example with 1 parameter

```js
const queue = ['Dave', 'Sarah', 'Sharon'];
const addCustomer = name => {
  queue.push(name);
};

addCustomer('Toby');

console.log(queue); // ['Dave', 'Sarah', 'Sharon', 'Toby']
```

You can omit `{}` from the above.

When there is a single parameter, the brackets `()` around the parameter can be omitted.

### Example with multiple parameters

```js
const addNumbers = (x, y) => x + y

console.log(addNumbers(1, 5)); // 6
```

### A useful example

```
const fruits = [
    { name: 'Apple', price: 2 },
    { name: 'Bananna', price: 3 },
    { name: 'Pear', price: 1 }
];
```

If we wanted to get the price of every fruit in a single array, in ES5 we could do:

```
fruits.map(function(fruit) {
    return fruit.price;
}); // [2, 3, 1]
```

In ES6 with the new Arrow Functions, we can make this more concise:

```
fruits.map(fruit => fruit.price); // [2, 3, 1]
```

Additional information on Arrow Functions can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 25):

This would be the "arrow function expression" introduced in ECMAScript 6.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions

For historical purposes (if the wiki page changes later), it is:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value. Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Comment: mind including enough info so most readers don't have to drill down?

Comment: The wiki I linked to very succinctly describes what it is: "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value. Arrow functions are always anonymous."

Comment: Adding that as a quote here will really help your answer.

Answer (score 22):

just to add another example of what a lambda can do without using map:

```
a = 10
b = 2

var mixed = (a,b) => a * b; 
// OR
var mixed = (a,b) => { (any logic); return a * b };

console.log(mixed(a,b)) 
// 20
```

Answer (score 14):

As others have said, it's a new syntax to create functions.

However, this kind of functions differ from normal ones:

- They bind the `this` value. As explained by [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation),

  > An *ArrowFunction* does not define local bindings for `arguments`,
  >   `super`, `this`, or `new.target`. Any reference to `arguments`,
  >   `super`, `this`, or `new.target` within an *ArrowFunction* must
  >   resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically
  >   this will be the Function Environment of an immediately enclosing
  >   function.
  >
  > Even though an *ArrowFunction* may contain references to `super`, the
  >   function object created in step 4 is not made into a method by
  >   performing [MakeMethod](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-makemethod). An *ArrowFunction* that references `super`
  >   is always contained within a non-*ArrowFunction* and the necessary
  >   state to implement `super` is accessible via the *scope* that is
  >   captured by the function object of the *ArrowFunction*.
- They are non-constructors.

  That means they have no [[Construct]] internal method, and thus can't be instantiated, e.g.

  ```js
  var f = a => a;
  f(123);  // 123
  new f(); // TypeError: f is not a constructor
  ```

Answer (score 9):

Dissatisfied with the other answers. The top voted answer as of 2019/3/13 is factually wrong.

The short terse version of what `=>` means is it's a shortcut writing a function **AND** for binding it to the current `this`

```
const foo = a => a * 2;
```

Is effectively a shortcut for

```
const foo = function(a) { return a * 2; }.bind(this);
```

You can see all the things that got shortened. We didn't need `function`, nor `return` nor `.bind(this)` nor even braces or parentheses

A slightly longer example of an arrow function might be

```
const foo = (width, height) => {
  const area = width * height;
  return area;
};
```

Showing that if we want multiple arguments to the function we need parentheses and if we want write more than a single expression we need braces and an explicit `return`.

It's important to understand the `.bind` part and it's a big topic. It has to do with what `this` means in JavaScript.

**ALL** functions have an implicit parameter called `this`. How `this` is set when calling a function depends on how that function is called.

Take

```
function foo() { console.log(this); }
```

If you call it normally

```
function foo() { console.log(this); }
foo();
```

`this` will be the global object.

If you're in strict mode

```
`use strict`;
function foo() { console.log(this); }
foo();

// or

function foo() {
   `use strict`;
   console.log(this);
 }
foo();
```

It will be `undefined`

You can set `this` directly using `call` or `apply`

```
function foo(msg) { console.log(msg, this); }

const obj1 = {abc: 123}
const obj2 = {def: 456}

foo.call(obj1, 'hello');  // prints Hello {abc: 123}
foo.apply(obj2, ['hi']);  // prints Hi {def: 456}
```

You can also set `this` implicitly using the dot operator `.`

```
function foo(msg) { console.log(msg, this); }
const obj = {
   abc: 123,
   bar: foo,
}
obj.bar('Hola');  // prints Hola {abc:123, bar: f}
```

A problem comes up when you want to use a function as a callback or a listener. You make class and want to assign a function as the callback that accesses an instance of the class.

```
class ShowName {
  constructor(name, elem) {
    this.name = name;
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
       console.log(this.name);  // won't work
    }); 
  }
}
```

The code above will not work because when the element fires the event and calls the function the `this` value will not be the instance of the class.

One common way to solve that problem is to use `.bind`

```
class ShowName {
  constructor(name, elem) {
    this.name = name;
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
       console.log(this.name); 
    }.bind(this); // <=========== ADDED! ===========
  }
}
```

Because the arrow syntax does the same thing we can write

```
class ShowName {
  constructor(name, elem) {
    this.name = name;
    elem.addEventListener('click',() => {
       console.log(this.name); 
    });
  }
}
```

`bind` effectively *makes a new function*. If `bind` did not exist you could basically make your own like this

```
function bind(functionToBind, valueToUseForThis) {
  return function(...args) {
    functionToBind.call(valueToUseForThis, ...args);
  };
}
```

In older JavaScript without the spread operator it would be

```
function bind(functionToBind, valueToUseForThis) {
  return function() {
    functionToBind.apply(valueToUseForThis, arguments);
  };
}
```

Understanding that code requires [an understanding of closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) but the short version is `bind` makes a new function that always calls the original function with the `this` value that was bound to it. Arrow functions do the same thing since they are a shortcut for `bind(this)`

Answer (score 8):

I've read, this is a symbol of `Arrow Functions` in `ES6`

this

```
var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });
```

using `Arrow Function` can be written as

```
var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions)

Answer (score 7):

Arrow functions which is denoted by symbol (=>) helps you to create anonymous functions and methods. That leads to more shorter syntax. For example, below is a simple “Add” function which returns addition of two numbers.

```
function Add(num1 , num2 ){
return num1 + num2;
}
```

The above function becomes shorter by using “Arrow” syntax as shown below.

[image]

Above code has two parts as shown in the above diagram: -

Input: — This section specifies the input parameters to the anonymous function.

Logic: — This section comes after the symbol “=>”. This section has the logic of the actual function.

*Many developers think that arrow function makes your syntax shorter, simpler and thus makes your code readable.*

If you believe the above sentence, then let me assure you it’s a myth. If you think for a moment a properly written function with name is much readable than cryptic functions created in one line using an arrow symbol.

> The main use of arrow function is to ensure that code runs in the
> callers context.

See the below code in which have a global variable "context" defined , this global variable is accessed inside a function "SomeOtherMethod" which is called from other method "SomeMethod".

This "SomeMethod" has local "context" variable. Now because "SomeOtherMethod" is called from ""SomeMethod" we expect it to display "local context" , but it displays "global context".

```
var context = “global context”;

function SomeOtherMethod(){
alert(this.context);
}

function SomeMethod(){
this.context = “local context”;
SomeOtherMethod();
}

var instance = new SomeMethod();
```

But if replace the call by using Arrow function it will display "local context".

```
var context = "global context";
   
    function SomeMethod(){
        this.context = "local context";
        SomeOtherMethod = () => {
            alert(this.context);
        }
        SomeOtherMethod();
    }
    var instance = new SomeMethod();
```

I would encourage you to read this link ( [Arrow function in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@shivprasadkoirala/arrow-function-in-javascript-471d13ad0af2) ) which explain all the scenarios of javascript context and in which scenarios the callers context is not respected.

You can also see the demonstration of Arrow function with javascript in [this youtube video I made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ik3RWl_-U3o) which demonstrates practically the term Context.

Comment: One of the better answers out there. Although I would have started with the sentence '=> is a shorter way of writing a function that takes in some parameters (on the left), and then does something with it(on the right).

Answer (score 6):

Adding simple CRUD example with Arrowfunction

```
 //Arrow Function
 var customers   = [
   {
     name: 'Dave',
     contact:'9192631770'
   },
   {
     name: 'Sarah',
     contact:'9192631770'
   },
   {
     name: 'Akhil',
     contact:'9928462656' 
   }],

// No Param READ
 getFirstCustomer = () => { 
   console.log(this);
   return customers[0];
 };
  console.log("First Customer "+JSON.stringify(getFirstCustomer())); // 'Dave' 

   //1 Param SEARCH
  getNthCustomer = index=>{
    if( index>customers.length)
    {
     return  "No such thing";
   }
   else{
       return customers[index];
     } 
  };
  console.log("Nth Customer is " +JSON.stringify(getNthCustomer(1))); 

   //2params ADD
  addCustomer = (name, contact)=> customers.push({
     'name': name,
     'contact':contact
    });
  addCustomer('Hitesh','8888813275');
  console.log("Added Customer "+JSON.stringify(customers)); 

  //2 param UPDATE
  updateCustomerName = (index, newName)=>{customers[index].name= newName};
  updateCustomerName(customers.length-1,"HiteshSahu");
  console.log("Updated Customer "+JSON.stringify(customers));

  //1 param DELETE
  removeCustomer = (customerToRemove) => customers.pop(customerToRemove);
  removeCustomer(getFirstCustomer());
  console.log("Removed Customer "+JSON.stringify(customers));
```

Answer (score 2):

As all of the other answers have already said, it's part of ES2015 arrow function syntax. More specifically, it's not an operator, it's a punctuator token that separates the parameters from the body: `ArrowFunction : ArrowParameters => ConciseBody`. E.g. `(params) => { /* body */ }`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, regular (traditional) functions use `this` from the object that called the function, *(e.g. a button that was clicked)*. Instead, arrow functions use `this` from the object that defines the function.

Consider two almost identical functions:

```
regular = function() {
  ' Identical Part Here;
}


arrow = () => {
  ' Identical Part Here;
}
```

The snippet below demonstrates the fundamental difference between what `this` represents for each function.  The ***regular function*** outputs `[object HTMLButtonElement]` whereas the ***arrow function*** outputs `[object Window]`.

```html
<html>
 <button id="btn1">Regular: `this` comes from "this button"</button>
 <br><br>
 <button id="btn2">Arrow: `this` comes from object that defines the function</button>
 <p id="res"/>

 <script>
  regular = function() {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = this;
  }

  arrow = () => {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = this;
  }

  document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", regular);
  document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", arrow);
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### `ES6` Arrow functions:

In javascript the `=>` is the symbol of an arrow function expression. A arrow function expression does not have its own `this` binding and therefore cannot be used as a constructor function. for example:

```js
var words = 'hi from outside object';

let obj = {
  words: 'hi from inside object',
  talk1: () => {console.log(this.words)},
  talk2: function () {console.log(this.words)}
}

obj.talk1();  // doesn't have its own this binding, this === window
obj.talk2();  // does have its own this binding, this is obj
```

### Rules of using arrow functions:

- If there is **exactly** one argument you can omit the parentheses of the argument.
- If you return an expression and do this on the same line you can omit the `{}` and the `return` statement

**For example:**

```js
let times2 = val => val * 2;  
// It is on the same line and returns an expression therefore the {} are ommited and the expression returns implictly
// there also is only one argument, therefore the parentheses around the argument are omitted

console.log(times2(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrow functions are roughly the equivalent of lambda functions in python or blocks in Ruby. **These are anonymous functions** with their own special syntax and **operate in the context of their enclosing scope**. This mean they do not have their own "this" but instead access the one from the immediate enclosing function.

From the [ECMA standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> An ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for **arguments**,
> **super**, **this**, or **new.target**. Any reference to arguments, super, this, or new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a
> binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically this will be
> the Function Environment of an immediately enclosing function.

Often you can read "an arrow function expression is a compact alternative to a traditional function expression", this is not a correct. **Arrow function are NOT a shorthand for traditional function**, they behave differently that traditional function.

**Syntax**

```
// Traditional Function
// Create their own scope inside the function
function (a){
  return a + 100;
}

// Arrow Function 
// Do NOT create their own scope
// (Each step along the way is a valid "arrow function")

// 1. Remove the word "function" and place arrow between the argument and opening body bracket
(a) => {
  return a + 100;
}

// 2. Remove the body braces and word "return" -- the return is implied.
(a) => a + 100;

// 3. Remove the argument parentheses (only valid with exactly one argument)
a => a + 100;
```

Comment: No functions in JS have a "fixed number of arguments"

Comment: @Bergi yes you right. I wanted to say "a syntax to accept argument", but this was misleading. I think it's self explanatory with the code snippet now.

Comment: Btw, they also have their own (variable) *scope*. They don't have a separate `this` value, which is often called *context*.

Comment: @Bergi fixed about the scope