# What happens behind the scenes with this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
(()=>{
console.log("Hello, world");
})();
```

How does this function work? It seems very obfuscated and I'd like a walkthrough of what's really happening.

Comment: Search for "ES6". `() =>` is (almost) the same as `function ()`, so this is a anonymous function that's immediately invoked. See also [this result via babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%28%28%29%3D%3E{%0Aconsole.log%28%22Hello%2C%20world%22%29%3B%0A}%29%28%29%3B).

Comment: First of all this is ES6 code, so not implemented everywhere for the moment

Comment: See also [the IIFE pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572)

Comment: @StrandedKid: Works in Chrome for me.

Comment: @FelixKling Yep but still it doesn't work everywhere :)

Comment: @StrandedKid: Oh, I somehow read "anywhere".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression,

```
() => {
console.log("Hello, world");
}
```

creates an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), introduced in the ECMAScript 2015 standard, and that is immediately executed with the function call expression `()` at the end.

---

Moreover, Arrow function definitions are actually function expressions only. So, you can omit the surrounding parens and write it as

```
() => {
  console.log("Hello, world");
}();
```

---

Apart from that, you have only one expression inside the arrow function. So, you don't need to create a block and write the same as

```
(() => console.log("Hello, world"))();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is ECMAScript 6. It creates an anonymous function, using the `=>` (called the "arrow" or "fat arrow") operator. The function does `console.log("Hello, world");` when executed. The code you posted then executes that function (the trailing `();`).

It breaks down like this:

```
( // wrapper for the function definition
    ()=>{ // use => to create an anonymous function
        console.log("Hello, world"); // body of the function
    } // end of the function definition
) // end of the wrapper for the function definition
(); // executes the function.
```

You can read more about arrow functions in [this prior answer that I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900924/2057919) or in [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions).

Answer (score 2):

it outputs a message to the web console.  [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) is a link to a page with the full API.

Comment: Welcome Rick. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.