# What's the meaning of "=>" in TypeScript? (Fat Arrow)

Tags: typescript

I just start to learn TypeScript, and I saw there is a lot of code using this sytax `=>`. I did some research by reading the [Specification of TypeScript Version 1.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md) and some googling. I still cannot understand the meaning of `=>`.

 To me, it feels like a **pointer** in C++. But I can't confirm it. If anyone can explain the following examples, that will be great. Thank you!

Below are some examples that I found when I was reading the specification of Typescript :

**Object Types**

```
var MakePoint: () => {  
    x: number; y: number;  
};
```

Question: What is this code doing? Creating an object called **MakePoint**, where x and y fields are **number** type? Is this a constructor or a function for `MakePoint`?

**Function Types**

```
function vote(candidate: string, callback: (result: string) => any) {  
 // ...  
}
```

Question: What is the meaning of `=> any`? Do you have to return a string type?

Can anyone explain to me the difference or the purpose of these examples in plain english? Thank you for your time!

Comment: This might also help: http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/arrow-function-typescript-tutorial/

Comment: Glad to see someone from C++ background posted this. Its tough to digest this kind of signs appear just next to function definition.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Perhaps you are confusing type information with a function declaration. If you [compile the following](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20MakePoint%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7Bx%3A%20number%3B%20y%3A%20number%3B%7D%3B):

```
var MakePoint: () => {x: number; y: number;};
```

you will see that it produces:

```
var MakePoint;
```

In TypeScript, everything that comes after the `:` but before an `=` (assignment) is the type information. So your example is saying that the type of MakePoint is a function that takes 0 arguments and returns an object with two properties, `x` and `y`, both numbers. It is not assigning a function to that variable. In contrast, compiling:

```
var MakePoint = () => 1;
```

produces:

```
var MakePoint = function () { return 1; };
```

Note that in this case, the `=>` fat arrow comes after the assignment operator.

Comment: If MakePoint is a function, why not just use regular JavaScript  function declaration? For example `function MakePoint() { ...} ` ?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin It is shorter and omits the name (`()=>...`), and it preserves the scope of `this` which means you no longer have to create `var self = this` variables, or pass `this` through function arguments. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: How can I access the property `x` and `y` in your example of `var MakePoint = () => 1` ? `x` and `y` are both assgined to `1`?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin In the first case [via `MakePoint().x`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20MakePoint%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7Bx%3A%20number%3B%20y%3A%20number%3B%7D%3B%0D%0AMakePoint().x). `MakePoint` is a function that returns an object with a property `x`. But in the second case, you must rewrite it as `var MakePoint = () => ({x: 1, y: 1});` (note the `()` around the object) so that it returns the object you want instead of the number 1 (which I was using as an example).

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking in your added question. Usually it is much easier to just ask a new question, since you have more space to explain what the question is. Also, if you add info later, this confuses readers and nobody will come back to look at your changes/new questions.

Comment: Ok. I will make it a new question! Thank you for the explanation. I need to digest a little bit to see if I can make sense myself on the updated question.

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function Maybe read this article it explains the fat arrow function really well with examples and use cases. I'm also a new learner like you and this article really help me understand the concept of fat arrows.

Answer (score 37):

In a type position, `=>` defines a function type where the arguments are to the left of the `=>` and the return type is on the right. So `callback: (result: string) => any` means "`callback` is a parameter whose type is a function. That function takes one parameter called `result` of type `string`, and the return value of the function is of type `any`".

For the expression-level construct, see [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: So in this case, is callback just the name of function?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin it is the name of a parameter, and the type of that parameter will be a function (but the name of whatever function you pass in as an argument can be anything)

Comment: this is actually the only answer explaining there is a difference between the fat arrow in typescript and in emca script

Comment: @ryan, can you explain what this means . `p => this.people = p` What does second equal mark do here?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator in JavaScript

Comment: yeah, but what is the meaning of the entire line? is it "p is a variable whose type can be any and it returns this.people of which the value is equal to p(at the right) ? " ? But anyway I cannot understand it. :(

Comment: @vigamage: It is equivalent to `(function (p) { return _this.people = p; });`

Answer (score 28):

```
var MakePoint: () => {  
    x: number; y: number;  
};
```

`MakePoint` is a variable. Its type is a function that takes no arguments and produces numbers x and y.  Now does the arrow make sense?

Comment: The above is the best answer.

Answer (score 15):

> *As a wise man once said "I hate JavaScript as it tends to lose the meaning of this all too easily".*

It is called the **fat arrow** (because `->` is a thin arrow and `=>` is a fat arrow) and also called a *lambda function* (because of other languages). Another commonly used feature is the fat arrow function `()=>something`. The motivation for a fat arrow is:

1. You don't need to keep typing `function`.
2. It lexically captures the meaning of `this`.
3. It lexically captures the meaning of `arguments`

---

```
function Person(age) {
this.age = age;
this.growOld = function() {
    this.age++;
  }
}

var person = new Person(1);
setTimeout(person.growOld,1000);

setTimeout(function() { console.log(person.age); },2000); // 1, should have been 2
```

If you run this code in the browser this within the function is going to point to window because window is going to be what executes the growOld function. Fix is to use an arrow function:

---

```
function Person(age) {
this.age = age;
this.growOld = () => {
    this.age++;
  }
}
var person = new Person(1);
setTimeout(person.growOld,1000);

setTimeout(function() { console.log(person.age); },2000);// 2
```

Answer (score 7):

It is called a "fat arrow".  It was added in EcmaScript6 and replaces the function keyword among other things.

More can be read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 3):

Directly from the link in OP:

> In this example, the second parameter to 'vote' has the function type
>
> (result: string) => any
>   which means the second parameter is a function returning type 'any' that has a single parameter of type 'string' named 'result'.

Answer (score 1):

Simply its been used in place of anonymous functions.

The below code

```
function(argument){
return argument. Length
}
```

will be transformed to `argument => {argument.length};`

For better understanding refer the below:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/arrow/