# What is this code doing? (.map and res)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I found this code online and can't seem to understand its purpose. Why is the `.map` method called twice, are the `res` variable the same in both method?

```
login(email, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
        '/login', 
        JSON.stringify({ email, password }), 
        { headers }
      )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res) => {
        if (res.success) {
          localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
          this.loggedIn = true;
        }

        return res.success;
      });
  }
```

Comment: i think that "=>" is for "lambda expression" in java is "->" for example, with this you can make a function for each element of the map.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274520/

Answer (score 2):

The operator `=>` is a lambda expression, it's just a short version of a function. For example, the code `a => a * 10` is the exact same thing as

```
function (a) {
    return a * 10;
}
```

The map function is comming from `RxJS`, you can check the documentation about it [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html). It, basically, just "update" the value of the returned value. These two variable are the same, just updated with the previous operation.

Basically, your code is making a `POST` request to the URL `/login` with a `JSON` containing the email and the password. It then edit the result from this request to a `JSON`, and with the result, it's checking if the value of `res.success` is true, if yes, you are storing the `auth_token` in the `localStorage`. Otherwise, you are just continuing the script and return the value of `res.success`.

Comment: I see thank you so much, so, .map(res => res.json()) means the response is converted into json format and then saved into 'res'. If the 'res' in the res.json() means Response, it does not need to be defined before this code? I did not see any 'res' before this code. so, I was not that clear. This json formatted 'res' has auth_token key inside? Thank you again.

Comment: Yep, it's exactly this.

Comment: thank you, so, is it correct in res=> res.json(), the first res has the json formatted value while the second res is 'Response'?

Comment: The first res is the parameter, it contains the original res, then you are applying the json filter on type, and re-assigning the new value to the initial res.