# Strange behaviour of the compilator, two same functions, first compile and second does not.

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn more about Generics function in TypeScript and I'm stuck on a compiler error.

I wrote two same functions but each one in a different way,

```
// FIRST FUNCTION
function genericFunctionOne<T>(first: T): T {
    return "Dummy return";
};

// SECOND FUNCTION
let genericFunctionOneBis: <T>(first: T) => T = first => "Dummy return";
```

the first one pass the compilator check but the second one does not.

> ts/assign.ts(3,12): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Is that an expected behaviour ? I don't understand why one function passes the compilator check and not the other.

Here are the transpiled javascript:

```
// FIRST FUNCTION
function genericFunctionOne(first) {
    return "Dummy return";
};

// SECOND FUNCTION
var genericFunctionOneBis = function (first) { return "Dummy return"; };
```

Comment: I guess its the first function that will fail

Comment: Actually the first one is what fails to compile, and the error is quite reasonable. I think the lambda version should give the same error, so this is probably a bug in TS.

Comment: it all fairness it should give an error in both cases. :-/ Also for me the first one fails and the arrow function succeeds.

Comment: You are returning a string for both, but the data type of the methods does not specify `string` so they should both fail, but only the first one does for me.

Comment: I understand they should both fail. But this is exactly why I'am asking this question, one fail and the other does not, event if the generated javascript behind is the same. I can invert the order of the function, and the arrow function will pass the compilator check anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is a subtle one, and there's another question that answers yours: [What's the meaning of "=>" in TypeScript? (Fat Arrow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274520/whats-the-meaning-of-in-typescript-fat-arrow)

Basically your first part:

```
let genericFunctionOneBis: <T>(first: T) => T
```

Only gives the information about the type of genericFunctionOneBis. Which in this case it is a function that accepts a parameter of type T, and returns something of same type T.

Second part, the assignment:

```
= first => "Dummy return";
```

That's your definition. Because you are not specifying type of first, it resolves T as being any, which means the definition matches the declared type of your variable.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but didn't I specified the type of `first` as `T` ?

Comment: The actual type inferred for arrow function is  `(first: any) => any` which is compatible with (first: T) => T when `any` is substituted in place of `T`.  You get an error for that with --noImplicitAny compiler option. More interesting question is why there is no error when you assign (first: number) => "Dummy return"  to genericFunctionOneBis even with  --noImplicitAny

Comment: As @artem said although you specified the type of first in the declaration, it is inferred from the assignment operation as any.