# (): meaning in javascript function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looking at a piece of code in a react application:

```
export const clickOptOutMessage = (): ClickOptOutMessage => ({
  type: CLICK_OPT_OUT_MESSAGE,
});
```

What does the `():` do? 
I am having trouble googling this due to the fact that it's just a bunch of characters.

Comment: You are missing typescript tag. Also to answer your question, its called [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `: ClickOptOutMessage` is a part of typescript, which means function will return value of type `ClickOptOutMessage`

Comment: Not sure if this is an exact dupe, but this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274520/whats-the-meaning-of-in-typescript-fat-arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain step by step (sorry if you already know everything except ending, some people may learn something new)

```
() => { /** function body goes here **/ }
```

is an arrow function

```
() => {} 
//basically equals:
(function () {}).bind(this)
```

It will always have context where it was written.

In TypeScript you can write function return type, like this:

```
function(): number {
  return 2;
}
```

So, now you know that since arrow function is just another function with slightly different syntax - (): TYPE is just a return type!

```
export const clickOptOutMessage = (): ClickOptOutMessage => ({
  type: CLICK_OPT_OUT_MESSAGE,
});
```

Somewhere in the code you looked at, there is this piece:

```
const CLICK_OPT_OUT_MESSAGE = "CLICK_OPT_OUT_MESSAGE"; // value can differ in code you observed

type ClickOptOutMessage = {
  type: "CLICK_OPT_OUT_MESSAGE"
}
```

As you can see,

```
(): ClickOptOutMessage
```

pretty much tells the type of return value.