# What's the meaning of "void = () => {}" after Fat arrow function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

I saw this block of code in our code base and I have a bit of a problem to understand `void = (page)`. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34274584/513413, the return type is coming after `=>` which is `void` in my case. So what does `= (page) => {}` do? 
What is its equivalent function if I don't write it with fat arrow function?

This is the code:

```
private navigateTo: (page: string) => void = (page) => {
    // display page
}
```

Comment: `= (page) => {}` says string (page) goes to this function which returns nothing (void).

Comment: The term "fat arrow function" has been obsolete for several years. They are called simply "arrow functions".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking at the code incorrectly. The general structure is

```
private Name: Type = Value
```

The type is `(page: string) => void` and the value is `(page) => {}`. The type means that `navigateTo` is a function that accepts a string as argument and returns nothing, which is what `(page) => {}` does.

Comment: Wow that took me a while to see... In my opinion I think that would have been better written as an `interface` for better readability

Comment: I don't know much about typescript, but I guess it could help if one could wrap the type in parenthesis: `private navigateTo: ((page: string) => void) = (page) => {}`

Comment: I take the `interface` part back, It would probably be better written like this: `private navigateTo(page:string): void { }`

Answer (score 5):

In Typescript, typings are inserted inside the statements of the language, transforming them a bit.

The code you submitted should read as such:

- `private navigateTo`: This part is straighforward. We create a private member called *navigateTo* inside the current class.
- `...: (page: string) => void`: This is the type of the member. In this case, it represents a function taking in a `string` parameter and not returning anything (void). This part is purely Typescript.
- `... = (page) => { /* display page */ }`: This is the actual function being assigned to the variable.

I recommend you read some of the [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html). It has a lot of information about the syntax and the language.