# Spring react - operator =>

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs

I am just learning Spring react, I don't know Javascript very well. I got to code:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    client({method: 'GET', path: '/api/employees'}).done(response => {
        this.setState({employees: response.entity._embedded.employees});
    });
```

There is written:

> componentDidMount is the API invoked after React renders a component
>   in the DOM.

I was looking for what Javascript operator  **=>** means. But don't found anything.

Comment: We know it is hard to find the duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an arrow function.

An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

You can see a simple example:

```
var vec = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'];

var test = vec.map(i => i.length);

alert(test); // 1,2,3
```

Comment: I think this is a poor answer without showing the previous/expanded/old method of writing anonymous functions (which the arrow function is a shortcut of) In this case, var test = vec.map(function (i) {
  return i.length;
});

Comment: A more detailed response is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas