# What does (state = {}) => state mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

I was building an App in react where I found a line in one of the boiler plate projects.

```
(state = {}) => state
```

Can anyone explain to me what the above line means?
It's **JavaScript ES6 standard.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of “=>” (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/1048572)

Comment: really not sure how this question got so many up-votes

Answer (score 9):

It is a(n arrow) function that returns its input. If the input is not defined it will become the default value {}.

You might have seen it in combination with using redux' "connect", as the function that maps the store's state to the projection used for the connected component. If there is no state available, the empty object will be provided.

Answer (score 8):

That's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) that returns its input or an empty object, if no input was provided. It is similar to this es-5 function:

```
function(){
    var state = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? {} : arguments[0];
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Default parameters don't replace falsy values.

Comment: Yes, now they should be equivalent.

Comment: That was weird, I didn't see this answer when I posted mine.

Comment: `var state = arguments.length < 1 ? {} : arguments[0]` What's wrong with that?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: It doesn't work when you explicitly pass `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi if you explicitly pass `undefined` to a defaulting parameter, does the default still override it? That seems unintuitive.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's how it is, yes. passing `undefined` is like passing nothing at all

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Yes it does. Passing no argument is the same as passing `undefined` - the parameter will have the value `undefined`.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks! I forgot to change the url... :)

Answer (score 3):

You might be more familiar with this notation:

```
function(state) {
    if (!state) state = {}; // state defaults to {}
    return state;
}
```

What you saw is ES6 syntactic sugar: `function(state = {}) { ... }` is a shorthand notation for default values (`state` defaults to `{}`), and `(a) => b` is a shorthand notation for `function(a) { return b }`. If you put them together, you get `(state = {}) => state`.