# ES6 class constructor arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking at an ES6 class definition and don't understand the arguments to the constructor. Here's the class:

```
export class Modal {
    constructor($modal, {size = null,} = {}) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I'm confused by this `{size = null,} = {}`. Is that a single argument? What does it mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get info on the object parameter syntax for javascript functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10804982/1048572) and [what does (state = {}) => state means](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35526463/1048572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a given default value.

If you pass an obj like

```
{ size: true }
```

you can access the "size" inside the constructor like a normal variable

```
export class Modal {
  constructor($modal, {size = null } = {}) {
    console.log(size); // prints the size value from the given object
  }
}
```

If you don't pass anything or you pass an object without "size", size will be null. You can make more of such assignments. Just seperate them by commas.

Example:

```
constructor($modal, { size = null, foo, bar = "test" } = {})
```

In this case if you pass an object without property "foo" it will be undefined, the rest acts like I mentioned above.

Also it's worth mentioning that you have to add `= {}` at the end of destructuring assignment in the `constructor` declaration. It's in case when you don't pass anything. Otherwise you would have to pass some object (may be empty).

Comment: Well, it's not really an assignment in this case…

Comment: @bergi It should be an object destructuring, right? Corrected