# Strange gulp syntax

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using Gulp v3.9.1, and have run across a gulpfile that is using a syntax that is foreign to me.  None of the tasks with this syntax will run.

```
gulp.task ('serve', [ 'js.lint', 'test' ], () => {
        onError = eatError;

        browserSync.init ({
            ui: false,
            files: [
                'index2.html',
                'tpl/**/*',
                opts.srcDir + '/assets/img/**/*',
                opts.srcDir + '/assets/less/**/*',
                opts.srcDir + '/app/**/*',
                opts.testDir + '/**/*',
                'src/main/coverage/**/*'
            ],
            proxy: {
                target: "localhost:8080",
                proxyOptions: {
                    xfwd: true
                }
            }
        });

        gulp.watch ([ 'gulpfile.js', opts.srcDir + '/app/**/*', opts.testDir + '/**/*' ], [ 'js.lint', 'test' ]);
    });
```

In particular, I am referring to the `() =>` on the first line.  That is what gulp is complaining about.  That syntax looks a little similar to a CoffeScript gulpfile I found, but I am not sure what it is.  The project using this gulpfile has a ton of packages, which I am sifting through right now to see if they have anything to do with this syntax.  I want to know what the `() =>` represents, and how to get tasks using this syntax to run.

Comment: es2015 lambda expression. "fat arrow function", you can replace it with an anonymous function (literally, just replace `() => ` with `function() `) or run it through babel first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: Hmm actually that might not be the best dupe - only talks about what `=>` actually is, not how to get it working in your environment.  Vote retracted.

Comment: @JamesThorpe To be fair, I did ask what `() =>` meant... so the dup you pointed to isn't irrelevant since it does answer part of what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the ES2015 syntax for an anonymous function with the outer scope's `this` as the context.

To get that syntax to work with gulp, make sure the file name is `gulpfile.babel.js` and not just `gulpfile.js`. Recent versions of gulp know to look for that file name and transpile it on-the-fly before running it, provided you have Babel installed.

Comment: how does this do anything? babel isn't going to intrinsicly find his files and convert them

Comment: @rlemon: Because it's built into recent versions of Gulp to support this, provided you have Babel installed. The gulpfile gets transpiled on-the-fly before being run.

Comment: Gulp implicitly handles babel compilation in Gulpfiles now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder TIL. should be mentioned in the answer then. I'll retract my -1