# Count number of times a character appears in string

Tags: javascript, string

So basically I need a script that summarizes which characters and the number of times they appear in a random string. Caps have to be ignored, for example:

```
var myString = promt ("Type anything: "); //"hello Hello";
```

The end result has to be something like this: `h = 2, e = 2, l = 4, o = 2` printed in the HTML document.

I've tried using `myString.match().length` without much success. My main problem is defining which characters to check and not checking characters twice (for example: if there are two "h" in the string not checking them twice).

Comment: Show us please what have you tried so far so we can help.

Comment: Also, your question is unclear. _"`not checking characters twice (for example: if there are two "h" in the string not checking them twice)`"_ But then in your example you have two "h" characters and you do count both of them.

Comment: This looks like a fun homework question.  Seeing as you've not posted more than a fragment of your code, have you tried using an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'hello Hello';
var count = {};
str.split('').forEach(function(v) {
    if (v === ' ') return;
    v = v.toLowerCase();
    count[v] = count[v] ? count[v] + 1 : 1;
})

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary object

```js
var o = {};

"hello Hello".toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/, '')
    .split('')
    .forEach(e => o[e] = ++o[e] || 1);

document.write(JSON.stringify(o));
```

This solution uses `arrow` function (`ES2015` standard) that doesn't work  in old browsers.

Comment: You should note that this only works in ES6. *See* [What's the meaning of “=>” (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24900924/2057919). It doesn't work in the versions of JavaScript available in many browsers. (And, of course, it's bad policy to do people's homework for them when they haven't made any real effort.)