# Accessing class scope from function expression in ES6

Tags: javascript, class, scope, ecmascript-6

In an attempt to simplify my question I originally wrote out a question that did in fact work. So let's suppose I have this code which uses D3 inside an ES6 class:

```
export default class MyClass{
    constructor(){
        this.radius = 1;
    }
    myFunc(){
        this.tooltip //defined elsewhere in the class don't worry about it
            .on('mouseover', function(){
                d3.select(this).transition()
                    .ease('elastic')
                    .duration('250')
                    .attr('r', this.radius*1.5);
                    //keyword this has now been overridden
            });
    }
}
```

But how can I achieve the above functionality, or should I be taking a different approach?

Comment: There is no such thing as "class scope". What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

*answering the [first revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36744193/1)*

The `this` in your event handler is the same as `this` in the `myFunc` method, but this has nothing to do with classes. The callback is an [arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/1048572), that's all. (There is no function expression in your code).

> But how can I achieve the above functionality, or should I be taking a different approach?

You already are achieving the desired functionality, and no you should not take a different approach.

Comment: while he is using arrow function everything will be ok, instead of anonymous function in that case he will get `undefined`

Comment: @The: If he had used a function expression instead of the arrow function, `this` would refer to the `#selector` element that jQuery passes into the handler.

Comment: probably i made something wrong with my example, but you can check it, when i'm clicking on button i get `undefined`. I know about jQuery that inside event handler `this` references to the element on which it has been fired. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxm4smc1/174/)

Comment: @The: `this` is the button, `this.myvar` is undefined of course.

Comment: @Bergi I'm actually using D3 not Jquery but same difference (see updated question) - but what you are describing is exactly my problem.

Comment: Looking at my code now it appears that its a name collision not a scope problem (?) and so perhaps I simply need to re-assign the `this` that refers to the class.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work as well. Can you explain first why an anonymous function and arrow expression have different behaviors?

Answer (score 0):

Now, looking at the new question, this still has nothing to do with classes.

> But how can I achieve the desired functionality?

You can't have `this` point to two different things, so you'll have to use a variable for at least one of them. The [default `var that = this` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) still works well:

```
myFunc(){
    var that = this;
    this.tooltip.on('mouseover', function(e){
         d3.select(this).transition()
            .ease('elastic')
            .duration('250')
            .attr('r', that.radius*1.5);
    });
}
```

(You can also use `var radius = this.radius;` if it won't change til the mouseover event).

Or you use [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/):

```
myFunc(){
    this.tooltip.on('mouseover', (e) => {
         d3.select(e.currentTarget).transition()
            .ease('elastic')
            .duration('250')
            .attr('r', this.radius*1.5);
    });
}
```

Or you even combine the two and don't use `this` at all, as it may be confusing what it does refer to.