# react native newbie questions '() =>' meaning?

Tags: react-native

What does that mean? How come I see it something used in the documents, but in practice through tutorials I don't ever see that?

example:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => SimpleList);
```

Is it just a new way of saying this:

```
function() { return SimpleList }:
```

ie:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', function() { return SimpleList });
```

Comment: Yes, it's called a lambda function and is practically the same as the other way of doing it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

`() => SimpleList` can be a replacement to `function() { return SimpleList }`

And no, you are not 100% right.
The `this` is same as the caller inside the arrow function, instead of a new this(new context) if you use function() {}

Check out this [(http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis) for more :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the fat arrow and the `function() { return SimpleList }` will work the same. The difference is if your anonymous function wants to use refer to `this`, in which case the fat arrow will "do the right thing".

For more info, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions