# What does "=>" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
function accum(s) {
  return s.split('').map((x,index) => x.toUpperCase()+Array(index+1).join(x.toLowerCase())).join('-');
}
```

I would like to know what "=>" is.  This function takes a string and for the index number of each element it adds that many elements to the output. Here's an example:

```
accum("abcd") --> "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
accum("RqaEzty") --> "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
accum("cwAt") --> "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

Comment: This is a new ES6 feature called "Arrow Functions".  See; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas

Comment: Yes, I found the other first

Comment: So can we have the link at the top be to the question @JJJ found? This question is "What is..." The supposed duplicate question linked above is "When do I..." Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a new feature that introduced in ES6 and is called arrow function. The left part denotes the input of a function and the right part the output of that function.

So in your case

```
s.split('')
```

splits the input on empty spaces and for each element of the resulted array you apply the following function:

```
(x,index) => x.toUpperCase()+Array(index+1).join(x.toLowerCase())
```

The left part is the random element, `x` of the array (`s.split('')`) and it's corresponding index. The second part applies a transformation to this input.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I'm going to guess it's because this a dupe of a well-known question and due to this answer it won't be deleted by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: so annoying... I'd be more than happy to correct my issue if someone would just tell me.  Anyways, thanks for answering my question. One more question, what is "Array()"... I can't find this method anywhere.

Comment: What I don't understand is the "Array(index+1)... I get what it's doing, but what is "Array()"?  I can't find this syntax/method/rule anywhere

Comment: The `Array(index+1)` creates an array of length `index+1`.

Comment: I understand this part, but I don't understand this syntax. a capitalized method? If i make the method "array(index+1)" instead of "Array(index+1)" it doesn't work.  Why?  What kind of syntax is this? I've never seen anything like this and I can't find it in the new ES6 documentation regarding arrow functions.

Comment: This is irrelevant with ES6. In order you get it, open developers tools and in the console write this, `var arr = Array(4)`. Then write, `arr.length`. As you guess you will get 4. Why? Because you have created an array of length 4. What are the values in the `arr`? Undefined ! You could check it fairly easy, if you write `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`,...

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array under Syntax.

Comment: I have never seen this, but this is very helpful. Thank you so much! I'd give you a million upvotes if I could.

Comment: @Twigs haha :) You are very welcome. I am glad that I helped !