# Why create a JS one-liner function to return a value we can already access?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

The following code is example code from an answer to a [question on arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405369/what-does-mean-in-javascript).

```
var a = [
  "We're up all night 'til the sun",
  "We're up all night to get some",
  "We're up all night for good fun",
  "We're up all night to get lucky"
];

// These two assignments are equivalent:

// Old-school:
var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

// ECMAscript 6 using arrow functions
var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );

// both a2 and a3 will be equal to [31, 30, 31, 31]
```

I'm new to javascript, so I'm wondering what's the point of defining a function this way at all? It seems to me it would be much easier to just pass in the `s.length` value itself. Even with more complex operations, it seems like it would make more sense to either save the output of those operations into a variable and pass that variable into the function `a.map` or just define the operations inside of the parentheses following `a.map`.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by `Even with more complex operations, it seems like it would make more sense to either save the output of those operations into a variable and pass that variable into the function`?

Comment: It's because `Array#map` expects a function that take an element of the array and return a new value.

Comment: What do you mean by _“just pass in the `s.length` value itself”_? Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: I get the feeling that this Q isn't so much about the usefulness of arrow functions but rather about a severe misconception about how callback using functions like `map()` work.

Comment: @ChrisG, that may be the case. Could you explain the misunderstanding?

Comment: @jaredad7 Could you address my first comment / Xufox's first?

Comment: Sure. By more complex operations, I mean something like, perhaps, a binary operation, eg `a.map(s.length - 1)`, or other such operations. By just pass in `s.length`, I mean something like `a.map(s.length)`. I see that @ibrahimmahrir mentioned that this particular function expects a function as input, but then the question is why doesn't it just take a single value (`s.length`), since that seems to be all it needs. I want to know why it's useful to do things this way.

Comment: `a.map(s.length)` wouldn’t work. What would `s` be? You’ve never defined that. In `(s) => s.length`, `s` is each string in the `a` array, for each iteration. JavaScript _could_ have a method similar to Underscore.js’s [`pluck`](https://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method, which could look like `a.pluck("length")`; but there is no such method.

Comment: Because JavaScript doesn't know what `s` is. It's simply not how JavaScript works (or any other programming language). All array functions expect a function as parameter, because that function is called on every element. To be clear, the arrow function is *already* partly syntactic sugar, meant to shorten lines as your `a2` one. Not sure what would be gained by saving 3 characters and making the code weird to read.

Comment: In addition, you can define a function elsewhere, then use it in multiple `map()` calls by simply passing its name. Like `const tolength = s => s.length;`, then later `var a2 = a.map(tolength);`

Comment: I was wondering about the necessity for creating a separate function in the first place. The fact that the `map()` function is using a function to run on each element answers the question. I didn't realize that's what was going on.

Comment: You have to distuinguish between a function and something else. In kotlin for example it is done by using different brackets for callbacks, e.g. `a.map(0)` just passes a value, `a.map { it.length }` passes a callback that is called for each array element where `it` is the element. However JS solved it differently.

Comment: @jaredad7 See the [`map` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It’s all explained there.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383321/5260024 for "why `forEach` at all?