# Why use '=>' for assignment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working through 'The CLI Book - Writing Successful Command Line Clients with Node.JS by Robert Kowalski' and he uses a pattern that I haven't seen before in Javascript.

I've got some code below, which uses '=>' as something like an assignment, but I cannot understand what it does.  I haven't seen Javascript use different assignment approaches that way 'R' might for example '=' vs '<-'.

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const files = glob.sync('*.js');
var arr = files.map(file => path.resolve(file));
console.log(arr);
```

The output is:

```
[ '/Users/jon/dev/js/a.js',
  '/Users/jon/dev/js/glob.js',
  '/Users/jon/dev/js/prime.js' ]
```

It seems that the file value is being declared and assigned in one, but if I modify the return statement to be the following:

`var arr = files.map(file = path.resolve(file));`

then it doesn't work and I get the following:

```
var arr = files.map(file = path.resolve(file));
                                        ^
ReferenceError: file is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jon/dev/js/a.js:4:41)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

I can't find reference to this '=>' operator anywhere in a bunch of books or on the web. He seems to use it in a number of places for example when defining a Promise:

```
function isOnline (url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({
      uri: url,
      json: true
    }, (err, res, body) => {
.
.
.
```

Any thoughts on what this is and why specifically this is being used instead of a normal assignment?

Jon

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas

Comment: Excellent - thanks.  I actually looked for '=>' in stackoverflow but it returned nothing so decided to ask.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a bit annoying to do a search of a symbol. It's usually better to google the name of the symbols in words to yield better search results. In this case, you would probably want to do something like "javascript arrow".