# What is the "=>" operator?

Tags: firefox

In [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Unit_testing) from MDN, it explains how to write a unit test for developing an addon for firefox. However, there are several segments that I don't understand and didn't find any useful result after searching google.

The first one, the following is a paragraph quoted from above link:

> In a web page, you can perform Base64 encoding and decoding using the 
>   btoa() and atob() functions. Unfortunately these functions are
>   attached to the window object: since this object is not available in
>   your main add-on code, atob() and btoa() aren't available either. So
>   we'll create a base64 module to expose these functions from the
>   platform (see Creating Reusable Modules).

What does "the platform" in the above paragraph mean? the "Services.jsm"?

Also in the following code:

```
const { atob, btoa } = require("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

this makes atob and btoa as one of the Services that is available for other class? or make (constant variables)atob and btoa both reference to the Services.jsm?

The Second one:
what are these two lines of code do?

```
exports.atob = a => atob(a);
exports.btoa = b => btoa(b);
```

I understand the part

```
exports.atob
```

which enables atob function to be available from other classes outside the "base64.js".
but what does the following mean?

```
= a => atob(a);
```

I didn't find that javascript has "=>" operator!

From my understaning, the reason we create a base64.js is because atob and btoa can only be called if we have the window object. Therefore we can use Services.jsm to get a reference of the window object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "platform" in the paragraph you quoted they mean the set of functions which is not strictly Firefox browser code but rather implements basic, share functionalities. This usually lives in [toolkit/modules](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/modules) in the mozilla-central repository. Services.jsm lives there as well so yes, that's part of the platform. Moreover, `atob` and `btoa` are both imported from Services.jsm.

The arrow `=>` in `exports.atob = a => atob(a);` defines what's called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): it's a new, shorter syntax to define functions in JavaScript. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) answer has many useful informations about it.

> From my understanding, the reason we create a base64.js is because atob and btoa can only be called if we have the window object. Therefore we can use Services.jsm to get a reference of the window object?

That's almost correct: you need to export the function from the underlying platform as you don't have a window object there. If you had a window object, you would have just done `window.atob` or something like that. That call would have still called the same function you imported from Services.jsm.

So you're not using Services.jsm to get a reference to the window object, but rather directly importing the needed functions so that you don't need to have a window object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! <br /> Can I say that Services.jsm is the bridge to export all the functions that bond to the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa
windowbase64?

Comment: Grrrr...I can only edit comments for 5mins, sorry for this following comment !

so can I say Services.jsm  can be used to export all the functions that are not available without window related objects? or it is a case by case situation?


I cannot believe that the '=>' was answered before on the forum! I did search "=>" and nothing showed up...really appreciate!

Comment: No problem! Services.jsm can be used to export all the function defined there, which may or may not be _all_ the functions.

Comment: I think where I stuck right now is after looking into Services.jsm's source code, I didn't find btoa() being defined inside Services.jsm.https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/modules/Services.jsm
besides, after `code`const { atob, btoa } = require("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
or btoa is defined in one of the module inside of Service.jsm?

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, I screwed up that one, sorry!
 
I think where I stuck right now is after looking into Services.jsm's source code, I didn't find btoa() being defined inside Services.jsm.
[link](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/modules/Services.jsm),or btoa is defined in one of the module inside of Service.jsm?
besides, after 'const { atob, btoa } = require("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");' atob contain the reference to the platform/Services.jsm or the real atob function? THX