# jQuery - difference between these function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a JS-class with some events

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn-details', (e) => {
```

but I can't access the data-attr tthe `.btn-details` has.

when I do a

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn-details', function() {
```

I can access the data-attr of the `btn-details`-element, but not the `this.myvar`-class-variable.

what is the problem here? what does this `(e) =>` exactly mean?

Comment: 1st answer is : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38582643/747579

Comment: Related: [What's the meaning of “=>” (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/218196), [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` contains the `click` event properties. it's commonly used with an global-like (`document` scoped) event like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn-details', (e) => {
   var btnDetails = e.target;
   var attr = btnDetails.data("attr");
}
```

or

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn-details', function(e) {
   var btnDetails = e.target;
   var attr = btnDetails.data("attr");
}
```

the original event receiver is the `document` element, because you had bound the listener method to it, but you can get the triggering element by querying `e.target` inside it.

Comment: thank you :) this explains it a way, even I can understand :)

Answer (score 2):

They both are function calls. The difference is that in first call, you use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with the event parameter (e).

**Arrow function**

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
```

As stated in the documentation

> An arrow function does not create it's own this context, rather it captures the this value of the enclosing context

So, I assume you are trying to get the data attribute using the `this` keyword

```
$(this).attr('data-test')
```

but, in arrow function, the `this` refers to the object of the **enclosing context**, not to the specific object.

---

The second one is a classic function call and `this` refers to the **clicked element**, so here you can successfully get the 'data-test' attribute.

---

**EXAMPLE**

Check this [live example](http://jsbin.com/rugote/edit?html,js,output)

In both buttons, the this object is writen in the console.log. Using the normal function the console outputs teh clicked element (the button) but, using the arrow function the console outputs the **window** object.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning** While they are both ways of defining a function, they are *not* the same. Read more details on [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Arrow functions automatically bind `this` to the current context.
If you are using `jQuery` this is a problem if you are trying to use `this` to refer to the current target.

```
$('div').click(function() {
  console.log(this) // the click target as expected
})

$('div').click(() => {
  console.log(this) // not the click target because jQuery can't bind it
})
```

If you want to use an arrow function, you can accept the event as an argument to your callback:

```
$('div').click((e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget) // click target as expected
  console.log(this) // enclosing context - could be useful
}
```

This can actually be handy if you want to keep track of the enclosing context from within the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Using an arrow ()=> function binds the "this" keyword from the original caller's "this" to the one inside the function scope.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to access the related elements (I mean without messing with `this` context) is to use the appropriate event properties.

- `e.target` refers to the actual event target
- `e.currentTarget` refers to the delegated event target (same as `this`)

So in your case you can always access the `.btn-details` element with `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: thanks a lot :) .. the advice wth delegated targets saved me a ton of time :)