# Lodash '=>' syntax meaning

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am working on an existing project and trying to move part of it to another build using gulp (grunt to gulp) and it seems one of the errors I am getting is the use of '=>' seeming to refer to lodash but I am not sure.

this is what one of the lins look like:

```
 Object.keys(highlightTerms).forEach((k) => { msg = _highlightList(highlightTerms[k], k, msg); });
```

and I am not sure why the error is being called or how I can change it so that the gulp builder compiles it.

This occurs in multiple files. Hopefully some light can be shed on this, I can't find anything related to it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Its ES6 features, equivalent to function (k) { msg = _highlightList(highlightTerms[k], k, msg); }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: Thanks Harry, also @self I obviously didn't know that, hence my question...

Comment: Object.keys isn't even lodash

Comment: but forEach is, at least from what I've seen, so if you don't want to help that's cool, again this goes with the fact, that I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is javascript ES6 syntax. It is a lambda function which is short hand for an anonymous function. It is equivalent to:

```
Object.keys(highlightTerms).forEach(function(k) { 
    msg = _highlightList(highlightTerms[k], k, msg); 
}.bind(this));
```

More information [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: The difference is that the arrow lambda inherits context from the caller, and anonymous function that you used here has its own context (I'm referring to value of `this`).

Comment: wait what is the 'bind' function for?

Comment: For your purpose, it is irrelevant and can be left off. I included it as @Mjh pointed out there is a difference as to the context of `this` which is assigned by default when using an anonymous function to using a lambda. Using bind like that sets the context of `this` to be the same context of the calling block.

Answer (score 1):

The `=>` syntax is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is only avalible in enviornments that support ES6, or ES2015. It's a shorter alternative to normal anonymous function notation.

You can fix the error either using a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) in your gulp workflow (which compiles ES6 to ES5), or by changing the syntax to the ES5 function expression.

Comment: thanks for the link to babel, I have looked into it and I am not sure how to incorporate it into my gulp. Right now it seems we are using wiredep.

Comment: also why doesn't gulp, by default use es6

Comment: @capa_matrix It's not gulp, it's whatever environment you're running the code in that doesn't support the new es6 syntax (yet). For example, node v6 and Chrome are almost fully supported, but Babel allows you to compile the code down to the old syntax for most browsers. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/