# what is the meaning of " = > " in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript-typings, typescript1.5, typescript1.6

I saw many code snippets which has  `=>`

symbol in typescript file. Could any one explain what is the exact meaning and why to use.

Comment: it's the es6 arrow function.

Comment: what is the arrow function ? why using this symbol for function ?

Comment: you should really just google that, stackoverflow is meant to help you with issues you are having in code not give explanations. :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: It's a closure whose scope remains unchanged. If you used `jQuery.proxy`, then `() => {}` is equivalent to `$.proxy(function(){}, this);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Answer (score 1):

=> is a lambda function. For a great intro take a look [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html), or the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).