# jQuery each nesting

Tags: jquery, each

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the following with jQuery? Is it possible to iterate through all the children, without nesting the `each` function?

```
$.each($('.my-class'), function () {
    $.each($(this).children(), function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

What if you have two or more elements with the class name `my-class`, how do you iterate through all of their children?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a single selector:

```
$('.my-class > *').each(function () {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Or chain selectors:

```
$('.my-class').children().each(function () {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: @skobaljic, I have no idea what you're talking about...j/k. I was lazy and used [arrow functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/497418) which was a poor choice because the example made use of `this`.

Comment: @skobaljic It's ES2015/ES6 syntax

Comment: Are you saying it cannot be done the way you did? You are also lazy to explain and therefore I am sad :(

Comment: It still says nothing about the syntax you used `() => {}`. Don't wanna bother you, have a nice day.

Comment: What if you have two or more elements with the class name my-class, how do you iterate through all of their children?

Comment: That function will go trough all the collection check this @Alexander https://jsfiddle.net/h7kb0nLt/

Comment: Yes, it actually does, Somehow I got it wrong the first time. Thanks

Comment: @skobaljic Here you go, this should give you an idea of what it's about: https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/ but zzzBov's link does cover it with plenty of detail

Comment: Thank you, it is a really nice article, would recommend to others.