# Declaring a function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I wanted to "update" my javascript code to the new ES6 Standard, so I looked at how functions are now written and tried it out on a global function of mine, which reads like this in the "old" es5

```
function logMessage(message) {
    document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML = document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML + `<li  class="item-padding">  ${message} </li>`
}
```

now if I'm not wrong the correct "transformation" to ES6 would be like this:

```
logMessage = message => {
    etc
}
```

But my ESLint tells me that my logMessage is not defined and I get an error in my console, do I miss something? Do I have to declare `var`, `let` or `const` before the logMessage?

I don't know if its important, but I also want to export this function from file One to file Two and use the function logMessage in another function in file Two, is there something I have to keep in mind when doing so?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Thanks everyone the answers helped me a lot, got my problem fixed!

Comment: I do not think the two are exactly the same: the first is a function declaration, the second is a function expression assigned to a variable

Comment: Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> now if I'm not wrong the correct "transformation" to es6 would be like this

You're wrong.

[Arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) are a new syntax with *different behaviour*. They are **not** a straight up replacement for function declarations and function expressions (both of which still exist in ES6).

> But my ESLint tells me that my logMessage is not defined and I get an error in my console, do I miss something? Do I have to declare var, let or const before the logMessage?

Yes. You're assigning something to a variable. [You must declare the variable first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors).

> I also want to export this function from file One to file Two

How you define the function has no bearing on your ability to export it.

Comment: I figured my 'answer' was more of an example, which suits your answer better: `const logMessage = (message) => {  // code }` would do.

Comment: () are optional with a single simple argument

Comment: @JaromandaX very true, although I prefer using them in cases like these for readabillity. (bad color coding on SE  (:!)

Answer (score 27):

```
function logMessage(message) {
    // etc...
}
```

... is function declaration which is still perfectly valid in es6. You are converting your function declaration into a function expression, which in es5 would look like this...

```
logMessage = function(message) {
    // etc...
}
```

... and then into es6 ...

```
logMessage = message => {
    // etc
}
```

... so the linting problem is not introduced by es6 syntax, but rather using function expression, assigning to a variable which without var/let/const is a global variable. There is also a difference in the original function declaration would be hoisted, but the function expression form must be declared before it's called. There is also a difference in that es6 arrow functions retain the context of this from the parent scope, so worth noting they are not 100% direct 1 for 1 mappings of each other.

Short answer, yes, variables need to be declared with `var`/`let`/`const` in order to avoid becoming global variables, whether it's a function or not.

```
let logMessage = message => {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate using `let` over `const` while declaring a function? I'd say a function should be immutable right?

Comment: @Roberrrt a function once declared can still be manipulated, so it's _mutable_. It is an object, after all. The `const` keyword just prevents it from being re-assigned further down. I don't think Billy Moon was "advocating" `let` over `const`, it's just the declaration keyword he happened to use, so it's for illustrative purposes rather than "this is the way you HAVE to do it".

Comment: @vlaz I've been using `const` myself, and haven't encountered any problems with it so far, but perhaps there was some magic possible when assigning it to a `let`, many thanks for the info though!

Comment: @Roberrrt well, there won't be "problems" with `const`. Unless you define a function `const func = x => x *2` then if you try to do `func = x => x +2` - that would throw a TypeError. However, you can still do, say, `func.toString = () => "this is awesome"` and this will _change_ the function - it's not immutable but that's not really what `const` does - it only protects from reassignment. So, the only problem this can cause is prevent you from overwriting a variable. It's usually quite rare that you'd want to do this with functions, anyway, so it's normally fine.