# Operator symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript

What does mean the "=>" symbol in javascript?

```
return (callback) => {
...
      data.forEach(res=> {
        response = mapResponse(res);
      });
}
```

Comment: It's called the arrow function in JavaScript.

Comment: See this: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875**

Comment: Also [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)