# What exactly does the anonymous JavaScript function f => f do?

Tags: javascript, lambda, ecmascript-6

I'm using a third-party library that has a function that takes functions as arguments. I'm doing some conditional checks to decide whether or not to add a particular function as a parameter and in some cases I don't want to provide a function. Providing null in that cases throws an error.

I found this code which works, but I don't fully understand what's happening.

```
compose(__DEV__ ? devTools() : f => f)
```

Is `f => f` equivalent to `() => {}` an empty anonymous function?

Comment: It returns an object literal of `f`, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_Syntax)

Comment: not empty anonymous, it is identity.

Comment: FWIW, [you can often stick constructs like this into babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=f%20%3D%3E%20f) to see what the equivalents in older versions of ECMAscript are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: That answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas doesn't directly answer this question. I knew f => f was an anonymous function I just didn't understand exactly what it was doing. I think this question is a specific case and the information provided by Felix King about identity functions is unique to this question.

Comment: *Just as a side question*, in which case could it be usefull?

Comment: Hey Mistalis, in redux the compose function acts like a pipeline, it's a function that takes functions as params and executes them from right to left. The return from each function gets passed to the next function. In my case I had functions that I only wanted to add to compose IF I was in development mode so in the case that I'm not in development mode, null or an empty anonymous function wouldn't work. The function needed to take a param and return that param...hence the function in question. http://redux.js.org/docs/api/compose.html

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`f => f` is similar* to `function(f){ return f; }`

So close, but not quite what you expected.

<sub>* - as has been pointed out in comments, there are subtle differences, but for the sake of your question, I don't think they are *particularly* relevant. They are very relevant in other situations.</sub>

Comment: I can think of at least two differences between `f => f` and `function(f) { return f; }` :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum cool, go ahead - even update this answer if you think its relevant.

Comment: I don't think it's very relevant, just a pedant: `new (f => f)` throws, it has a different `toString` and for some reason I can't quite grok `(f => f).arguments` throws in Chrome but not FF or Edge.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the handling of `this` is also different. (although the difference might not be observable if `this` doesn't appear in the function body... I'm not sure)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well, according to the current spec, the arrow function itself [must not have its own `caller`/`arguments` properties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-forbidden-extensions), and [the ones on **Function.prototype**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addrestrictedfunctionproperties) (see [CreateIntrinsics](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createintrinsics)) are defined to throw on access.  Possibly things were less precise in 2016?

Answer (score 192):

`f => f` is the [**identity function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function). It simply returns the argument that was passed in.

This function is often used as a default values for transformation processes, since it doesn't perform any transformation.

> Is `f => f` equivalent to `() => {}` an empty anonymous function?

No. The empty function doesn't return anything. The identity function returns the passed in argument.

Comment: A+ for providing name, explanation, and a use case, and answering the actual question.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to know what `f => f` means, the left side is the parameter and the right side is the return value. So for example, `f => f*2`, is equivalent to:

```
function(f) { 
  return f * 2; 
}
```

The code which you describe returns whatever is supplied to it as input.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 9):

Others have already mentioned what `f => f` does, so I'm not going to go deeper into that. I'm just going to explain the rest of the function, because there's a bit of a difference between `f => f` and `__DEV__ ? devTools() : f => f`

The ternary operator checks if `__DEV__` is a truthy value, and if so, it return function `devTools()`. otherwise, it return the identity function `f => f` which does nothing. Put differently: this code enables some development mode functions. Without the remaining code, it's hard to tell what this mode adds, but presumably, it will enable some extra logging information and less obfuscation.

Comment: `__DEV__ ? devTools() : f => f` does not assign anything to `f`. Did you leave something out from the code example?

Comment: It will not return the function, it will return the result of the function

Comment: Your avatar annoys me and disturbs my day. I feel like 90's and my modem lost the connection. Still, +1 anyway, for a good answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You are not the first one to comment on my avatar. You're the first one who doesn't like it though. Most people appreciated the nostalgic factor and the small subversion of expectations it invokes.

Comment: I hope that you got the irony, mate. It was meant as a joke, of course. Obviously, I like it and I find it refreshingly original.

Answer (score 9):

Anytime with the similar dilemma, you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=f%20%3D%3E%20f%0A) to get the answer.

It returned like this:

```
"use strict";

(function (f) {
  return f;
});
```

BTW, **=>** you used is ES6 feature called [arrow expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
The other expression of interest

```
() => {};  // es6
```

would convert to:

```
(function () {});
```

Since arrow function expressions are always **anonymous** it makes sense if you add the name to the function:

```
let empty = () => {}; // es6
```

would convert to

```
var empty = function empty() {};
```