# Understanding arrows in ES6

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Based on a reference:

> Arrows are a function shorthand using the `=>` syntax.

Well I cannot understand it as well. How can I write following code by using `function` in it literally?

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component2', () => Component2);
```

---

Ok, lets focus on this:

```
() => Component2
```

- What's `()`? Is it the value I want to pass?
- What's `=>`? Is it a alternative for the word of `function`? So we can write it as `() function Component2` ? *(I hardly think so)*
- What's `Componenet2`? Is it the name of a function? Or a class? or what exactly?

Comment: Componenet2 is an object name which you defined as a component at the top of the file. It just gets returned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas). You can also refer to [SO - Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/5007/arrow-functions#t=201704120555467344431)

Answer (score 2):

This `() => Component2` is equivalent to the following:

```
function(){
    return Component2;
}
```

So the empty parentheses `()` in the left denotes that your function has no parameters, whereas the arrow `=>` denotes what you function returns.

Below there is a snippet, in which we have a function that expects two values and returns their sum.

```js
var add = (x,y) => x+y;
console.log(add(3,4));
```

A detailed documentation of the arrow functions can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: I see, thank you. upvote. May you please give me a example which contains a function passing some arguments?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure thing, please check my update.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite it without es6 as :

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component2', function(){
 return Component2;
});
```

The format basically in this case is :

```
(arguments) => returnValue
```

You can pass an argument like so:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component2',(arg1, arg2) => Component2);
```

A more generic example with arguments would be:

```js
var print = (message) => console.log(message)
print('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 2):

`() => Component2` explanation in ES06:

`()` means anonymous `function` with no argument,  `=>` special symbol or ES06 arrow functions.  `Component2` is the returned value.

In general it represents like:

```
function(){
    return Component2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component2', () => Component2);

lets focus on () => Component2;

say if you have a function like this in ES5:

```
function fun(a,function(){ console.log(a);});
```

In ES6 it can be written as :

```
function fun(a,()=>{console.log(a)});
```

So you can say it is just a shorthand for writing functions in new ES6 way

In your case Component2 is an object in above example the code can be written  as :

```
var obj = {console.log(a)};
function fun(a,()=>obj);
```

The result will be same.

Answer (score 1):

> What's ()? Is it the value I want to pass?

`()` is the syntax for declaring a function's arguments, in this case there are no arguments.

> What's =>? Is it a alternative for the word of function? So we can write it as () function Component2 ? (I hardly think so)

It is not a direct alternative for `function`, and no, you can't just insert the word function there and expect things to work. The alternative to the arrow syntax is `function() {}`.

> What's Componenet2? Is it the name of a function? Or a class? or what exactly?

It's most likely a class, (and probably a React component, based on the name) because it is in CamelCase, which is how classes are written in Javascript. `() => Component2` is an arrow function which takes no arguments and returns `Component2`.