# jquery(selector).each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) for webpage.The gridster widgets are `<li>` elements placed in `<ul>`.I generating these widgets with the help of json.

I am passing the values of json to `add_widget` function of gridster which dynamically generates the `widgets(li elements)` for me.

The gridster has a builtin function [serialize](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/serialize.html) which generates a json encoding the widgets present.

I have modified the `seriazlize` function to return an extra
key value pair which can capture the content of textarea on the widgets.

Following is the function which helps in getting the extra key value pair

```
function serialize() {
    var s = gridster.serialize();
    $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el) => { // grab the grid elements
        s[idx].images= $('.imagenames', el).val(); // extract content from textarea with class:imagenames
        s[idx].title = $('.hoverinformation', el).val();  // extract content from textarea with class:hoverinformation

              json_variable = JSON.stringify(s)
    });
    $('#log').val(json_variable);

}
```

In the above function I am getting that element with class `gridster` is selected inside that `<ul>` is selected and in that each `<li>` is selected.

But I was not understanding what is `.each((idx, el) => {`  this part

Also what is `idx` and `el` and this line entirely `s[idx].images= $('.imagenames', el).val();`.

HTML:

```
<div class="gridster">
<!--  <li> from JSON are placed here -->
    <ul>

    </ul>
     <button class="js-seralize btn btn-success mr-2"> Serialize </button>
     <textarea class="textarea form-control" id="log"></textarea>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8h5hdn0/1/) representing the same

Comment: `s` is an array of items, `idx` is the index of the items you are looping (or `each`-ing) over, and `el` is the actual element being looped. `(idx, el)` are the arguments of an arrow function, with the arrow linked the arguments and the actual executable function body. So `.each((idx, el) => { ...execute stuff with arguments... })` is equal to, say, `.each(function( idx, el ){ ... execute stuff with arguments... })`

Comment: NewBie, Type: Function( Integer index, Element element ) 

This is from https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I was not understanding what is `.each((idx, el) => {` this part

`$('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el) => {` is an arrow function. `idx` and `el` are the arguments that the handler function receives (see the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each) for more information on that).

The arrow function is equivalent to this:

```
$('.gridster ul li').each(function(idx, el) { ...
```

However there are a couple of caveats. Firstly the function handler retains the outer scope when using an arrow function definition, so `this` would refer to the `serialize()` function itself, not the `li` being iterated over. Secondly, it's completely unsupported in IE.

> Also what this line entirely `s[idx].images = $('.imagenames', el).val();`

That line is setting the value of the `images` property of the object at index `idx` within the `s` array to the value of the `.imagenames` input within the `el` element.

Comment: Can you please explain the first caveat I was not getting it

Comment: Hopefully this demo should show it more clearly: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/wLpxp9kt/

Comment: My understanding of this is `$('.imagenames', el).val();` .Search an element with class image names in the element `el` and get its value with `val();` and assign it to key images. Is that correct

Comment: I may have just put it in a different way what you have said sorry for it then.All this is bit difficult for me to grasp at this pace

Comment: Your understanding is correct. No need to apologise at all :)

Comment: Thanks for understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

`.each((idx, el) => {` is a `forEach` loop over every element of the array coming from `$('.gridster ul li')`. `el` represents the object and `idx` is the index of the element in that array.

Answer (score 1):

> But I was not understanding what is `.each((idx, el) => {` this part

That's passing an [arrow function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) into jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). `each` will call the function for each entry in the jQuery set it's called on (in that case, the one created by `$('.gridster ul li')`).

> Also what is `idx` and `el`

When `each` calls the function, it passes the index of the element in the set as the first argument, and the element itself as the second argument. So `idx` is the index in the set, and `el` is the element.

> and this line entirely `s[idx].images= $('.imagenames', el).val();`.

That's looking up the object in `s` for index `idx` and creating/updating an `images` property on the object, assigning it the value of the first descendant element within `el` that has the class `imagenames`. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in the jQuery documentation.