# Lodash: Extract property, split array, get unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, lodash

In my JS project, I am using Lodash library to Extract property, split array, get unique values.

```
  var taskobj = [
      {'taskno':'a', 'team':'1,2'},
      {'taskno':'b', 'team':'3,4'},
      {'taskno':'c', 'team':'2,4'},
    ];

 //Looping through the object to convert string to array
  _.forEach(taskobj, function(value, key) {
    taskobj[key].team = _.split(taskobj[key].team,',');
  });

// using _.map to extract team and return array
// using _.flatten to flatten array
// using _.uniq to get unique values from flattned array.

return _.uniq(_.flatten(_.map(taskobj,'team')));
// logs - [1,2,3,4]
```

Is this the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: `var teams = [];
taskobj.forEach(o => teams.push(...o.team.split(',')));
_.uniq(teams);` You can modify this to add a condition to check if element exists in the `teams` array before pushing and remove `uniq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using [`lodash#flatMap`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMap) with an iteratee that splits the `team` string into an array, which is then flattened by the mentioned function and then use [`lodash#uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniq) to get the final result.

```
var result = _.uniq(_.flatMap(taskobj, ({ team }) => team.split(',')));
```

```js
var taskobj = [
    {'taskno':'a', 'team':'1,2'},
    {'taskno':'b', 'team':'3,4'},
    {'taskno':'c', 'team':'2,4'},
];

var result = _.uniq(_.flatMap(taskobj, ({ team }) => team.split(',')));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `({ team }) => team.split(','))` I am relatively new to JS

Comment: Got it, it's arrow function (shorthand for function without a name) Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900924/4050261

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha also note that the `team` string was extracted with the use of [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: I used lodash `_.split(arr,',')` instead of `arr.split(',')` as lodash takes care of null values.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and start with a [new Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and add the values of `team` every time ( then convert it back to an array with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) )

```js
var taskobj = [
  {'taskno':'a', 'team':'1,2'},
  {'taskno':'b', 'team':'3,4'},
  {'taskno':'c', 'team':'2,4'},
];

var result = [...taskobj.reduce((acc, {team}) => {
  team.split(',').forEach(e => acc.add(e))
  return acc
}, new Set())]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simpler version

try this

```
var teams = [];
var taskobj = [
      {'taskno':'a', 'team':'1,2'},
      {'taskno':'b', 'team':'3,4'},
      {'taskno':'c', 'team':'2,4'},
    ];

taskobj.map(obj => {
  var teamSplit = obj.team.split(',');
  teams = [...teams, ...teamSplit];
})

var uniqTeams = _.uniq(teams);
console.log('teams', teams);
console.log('uniqTeams', uniqTeams)
```

JsBin link
http://jsbin.com/bedawatira/edit?js,console