# What do you call this type of code? Is it a closure?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, theory

The app at my work (React.js) requires me to pass functions around a lot, and often I have to do this: (es6 javascript)

`({ ...args }) => this.props.exampleFunc({ newArg, ...args })`

Taking a func I had and doing this to inject an argument without calling it. I was reading about closures and I thought that might be what this, but I wasn't sure I fully understood. Is that what this is?

Edit: to clarify, I'm not talking about the arrow, I'm just talking about the trick with the newArg

Comment: Yes, the arrow function closes over `this`, making it a closure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: @Igor I'm not talking about the arrow, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I am not following, what trick with `newArg`? It is an assigned value on a new object that is being passed into the `exampleFunc`, it probably exists outside the function I am thinking but without more code I could not say.

Comment: That's what I'm referring to. Just wondering if there was a name for doing that.

Comment: IE. if a function took in three arguments, and you did this so that it only required two arguments

Comment: `{ newArg, ...args }` is shorthand for creating a clone of the original object argument and adding an additional property to it.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `(argObj) => this.props.exampleFunc(Object.assign({ newArg }, objArg))`

Answer (score 0):

It's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and yeah, it's a sort of a closure (if it uses names from the outer scope).

Compared to regular ol' `function() {}` functions, arrow functions also capture `this` from the outer scope, which is useful in all sorts of object-oriented situations.