# Angular 2+ Observables and Javascript Syntax

Tags: javascript, angular

I am quite new to Angular and Javascript, so I was wondering what the following syntax means:

```
const simpleObservable = new Observable((observer) => {    
    // observable execution
    observer.next("bla bla bla")
    observer.complete()
})
```

Why is the argument "`(observer)`" passed in parenthesis to the Observable constructor, and what is the arrow syntax `=> {...}` doing?
where can I read about those special constructs in javascript syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: `observer` does *not* need to be passed within parenthesis. You only need parenthesis if you include the data type e.g. `(observer: any)` or if you have more than one parameter e.g. `(observer, someOtherValue) =>`

Comment: Here is a link to the docs on using an arrow function in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

The `() => {}` syntax denotes a *lambda expression*. Specifically, a TypeScript lambda expression where the `this` pointer is set to the actual class (instead of the lambda invoker).

JavaScript lambdas (`function() {}`) should be avoided as they do *not* maintain the integrity of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the arrow syntax => {...} doing?

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are a type of function introduced in the 2015 version of javascript. They are shorter to write and unlike normal functions they take their value of `this` from the context in which they're declared, not the context in which they're invoked. (though in your particular case, `this` is not being used, making that distinction irrelevant)

The equivalent using old style functions would be:

```
const simpleObservable = new Observable(function (observer) {
  // observable execution
  observer.next("bla bla bla")
  observer.complete()
});
```

> Why is the argument "(observer)" passed in parenthesis to the Observable constructor

To construct an observable from scratch, you pass in a function which describes how to do whatever it is you want done. When someone calls `.subscribe` on the observable your function gets called, and you can do whatever asynchronous stuff you need. And when you have something to report, you can use the `.next`, `.complete`, and `.error` callbacks to output the results.