# How to redirect user to new page on div click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to load a new URL depending on which div was clicked. Every div has its own URL for loading (in my implementation divs are blog pages).

**My JQuery:** & **My html:**

```js
$('.postWraper').click(() => {
        window.location = $(this).find('h3').find('a').attr('href');
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postWraper">
    <h3 class="postTitleH3">
        <a href="blog/first-page" class="postTitle">
            <%= post.postTitle %>
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="postWraper">
    <h3 class="postTitleH3">
        <a href="blog/second-page" class="postTitle">
            <%= post.postTitle %>
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

When I clicked on first or second div it's allways redirect me to first URL. I can't understand why. Please help!

Comment: maybe your html is broken or false?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/822/

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior of browsers? Why are you writing a script for it?

Comment: When running your code, `$(this).find('h3').find('a').attr('href')` is returning `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [meaning of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) is changed because you're using arrow function as the event handler. Change that to a regular function:

```
$('.postWraper').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('h3').find('a').attr('href');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to change the arrow function. You can still make it work by passing the event object in `click` event and using `e.target.href;` to get the `href` value:

```js
$('.postWraper').click((e) => {
  window.location = e.target.href;
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postWraper" id="<%= post.id %>">
    <h3 class="postTitleH3">
        <a href="blog/first-page" class="postTitle">
            Some title
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="postWraper">
    <h3 class="postTitleH3">
        <a href="blog/second-page" class="postTitle">
            Some title
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```