# Are there any differences between f = ()=>{} and f = function () {}

Tags: javascript, function

When we use `()=>{}` we cannot get arguments in it, but we can use arguments in `function(){}`. Why? I thought `() => {}` is just an another way of `function() {}`. Now it means I was wrong.

Comment: Really good question ! But sadly this is somewhat a duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas

Comment: Read the first para here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions