# javascript ES6 class implementation across several files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to separate a class implementation across different files, and I did it this way:

A.js:

```
export default class A {
   constructor() {
     this.a = 0;
   }
}
```

B.js

```
import A from ...

A.prototype.foo = (n) => { this.a = n; };
```

But the problem is that when I call `foo`, `this` is undefined.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: You're using an `=>` function. Change it to a classic `function` function and it'll work.

Comment: @Pointy why?....

Comment: Because like this the context of definition of it is not the prototype object?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm looking for a dup but I have some sort of psychic block with finding them :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: @luc4s you sure that `this` is undefined? rather then `a` being undefind?

Comment: Wow  I didn't know about the difference between the two, thank you! (it worked)

Comment: Biggest problem with arrow functions, is that a lot of newcomers to JS assume it's just a shorthand for `function()`, but it does more than this.  It also binds `this` to the current `this`, during the OP's assignment `this` will be undefined.