# What does the following code mean??And how should I understand the syntax of the function body?

Tags: javascript

```
createFilter(queryString) {
  return (restaurant) => {
    return (restaurant.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryString.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  };
}
```

I'm wondering that why the first `return` is followed by another `return`, and what dose the symbol `=>` mean? How should I comprehend the whole piece of code?

Comment: `createFilter` is a method from some class, which returns a function that only matches restaurant starting with the queried string.

Comment: It could however, be just: `return restaurant => RegExp(queryString, 'i').test(restaurant);`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes doesn't have to be on a class. You can create a function on an object the same way

Comment: @MatthewHerbst You are completely right... I just tested it out, thought it was a class only syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: @Raymond Chen the code is from the element ui offical website.When I studied the element ui conponent from its offical website,I found I couldn't understand this piece of code.So I asked it myself on SO after I couldn't find the satisfied question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=>` symbol is just another way of declaring a function. This type of function is known as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (or sometimes referred to as a lambda function). For example, `(restaurant) => {...}` can be re-written as:

```
function(restaurant) {...}
```

While this isn't exactly the same as the arrow function, it will help you understand what's going on in your code. To understand the core difference between arrow functions and plain function syntax, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch).

As for the code logic, if you look at the inner-function by itself it may become clearer what's happening:

```
(restaurant) => {
  return (restaurant.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryString.toLowerCase()) === 0);
};
```

This is a function, which accepts a `restaurant` as an argument. The function then uses the `restaurant` to `return` a value *once called*. In this case, the return value is a boolean.

If you were to call the entire function above `x`, then your entire code would look something like:

```
createFilter(queryString) {
  return x;
}
```

Here, it is clear that that the function `createFilter` will accept an argument, `queryString`, and return `x` which we know is a function.

So, if I was to call `createFilter("foo")`, it would give me the function `x`, which we said is equivalent to:

```
(restaurant) => {
  return (restaurant.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryString.toLowerCase()) === 0);
};
```

So, now, as we know `x` is a function, we can call it `x("bar")`. We can see that the above function will return a boolean (as it is doing a comparison), and so calling `x("bar")` will result in either `true` or `false`.

Full usage of the `createFilter` function will thus looking something like:

```
let filter = createFilter("foo"); // returns a function (x), we can store the returned function in a variable called "filter"
let found = filter("bar"); // call the function stored in the variable filter
```

Or, by removing the itermidiate variables, it can be written as one-line:

```
let found = createFilter("foo")("bar");
// returns a function--^^^        ^^---- executes the returned function
```

Comment: I think I've understand the code completely, thank you so much for your excellent answer~

Comment: @wangzewei no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

`(restaurant) => { }` is a function. More specifically it is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Sounds like you have a lot of JS reading to do. What the code is doing: `createFilter` returns a function (`=>` is an "arrow function") which when called, returns the `true` or `false` based on if the comparison holds. The comparison is checking if `queryString.toLowerCase()` matches the first letter (`indexOf` where the index is `0`)  of `restaurant.value.toLowerCase()`.

So for example, you could call it like:

```
const myFilter = createFilter('A');
myFilter('Algerian Food'); // true
myFilter('Italian Food'); // false
```

Comment: whether the whole code means that the first `return` calls the following function, and passes the parameter: `restaurant` which the function uses it to do the match thing.@Matthew Herbst