# Could someone explain arrow functions? (ES6)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand arrow functions at the moment.

I know that with arrow functions the scoping is a bit different. However, I'm still kind of confused on how it all works.

Here's an example that I don't understand all that well.

```js
// ES5
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter: function counter() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
};
```

Now, here's that exact same code block but with arrow functions used.

```js
// ES6
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter: function counter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.id);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

Looking at it, it seems to me it's all about the levels. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but with ES5 we would use the `.bind()` method in this instance because without it, it would return as undefined. I assume this is because in this instance, the `this` keyword in `console.log(this.id);` is referring to the `counter` object and by default, it could not find the `id` of the `obj` object.

Kind of confusing but I think that's it. Now, with the arrow functions, I'm not sure why `console.log(this.id);` would work. Does this mean as long as it's in the same code block, it could be used?

Much appreciation!

Comment: *The `this` keyword in `console.log(this.id);` is referring to the counter object* `->` **No**, is referring to `obj`.

Comment: With arrow functions, `this` refers to the context in which the code is _written_ (also known as 'lexical binding'). With es5 functions, `this` refers to the context from which the code is _called_. So in this case where you want `this` to refer to `obj`, you need to call bind.

Comment: Relevant, if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/497418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example if you wouldn't use `bind()`, then `this` would refer to the `setTimeout` callback. Because you used `.bind()` you changed the `this` reference to the `obj` object. That's why you got the `42` as `this.id`.

In the second example, `bind()` is not required because arrow function does not have its own `this`, it's the same as the parent `this`, so in this case it's pointing to the `obj` object and that's why you also get `42` as the `this.id`

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this):

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not present in current scope they end up finding `this` from its enclosing scope.

Arrow function is doing exactly what `.bind(this)` does. Both your examples are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone says ES6 arrows function don't have a `this` so they can use the `this` of their "parent". 
But there also another différence in ES6 you din't notice: in js objects ,you dont need to use the `function`  word, as follow

```js
// ES6
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.id / 7);
    }, 1000);
  }
};

console.log('start')
obj.counter();
```