# If Else Statement is not being executed

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, contact-form

I have a contact form, which includes required fields. I have written an If else statement so that if the required fields are empty, the form will not be sent and if it is, the form will be sent and cleared. The If part of the statement is executing, but the else doesn't seem to be. I am still learning Javascript so i have probably done something incorrectly.

I have tried looking at looking at layouts of If else statements and amending mines, but this has not helped.

```
<form name="myForm" class="contact-form" 
action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="text" name="yname" class="contact-form-text" 
placeholder="Your Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="yemail" class="contact-form-text" 
placeholder="Your Email" required>
    <textarea class="contact-form-text" name="ymessage" placeholder="Your 
Message" required></textarea>
    <input type="reset" class="contact-form-btn-reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" class="contact-form-btn" onClick="return 
submitForm()" value="Send">

    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"][yname][yemail][ymessage].value;
        if (x == "") {
          alert("Please complete form.");
          return false;
        } else {
          alert("Your message has been sent.");
          var frm = document.getElementsByName('myForm')[0];
          frm.submit();
          frm.reset();
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </form>
```

When the submit button is pressed, i'm expecting the form to submit with an alert and clear (if all fields are completed), if all fields aren't completed i expect the form to not submit.

Comment: Have you tried the `onsubmit` event on the `<form>`? Instead of the `onclick` event on a button?

Comment: There is no variable named `yname` in your code, this should be erroring

Comment: Andy, that the `name` of the `input` being validated.

Comment: Yes, but you're using it like a variable here.

Comment: If you are setting a `required` attribute you don't have to do any of those check. The form will be rejected if the elements marked as required does not meet the specific requirement. As of clearing the form just do `if ( document.forms["myForms"].checkValidity() ) { submit and clear }`. The check validity is redundant but i used it incase someone removed the `required` attribute via the console

Comment: Andy, I see now, it should be in quotes.

Comment: `document.forms["myForm"][yname][yemail][ymessage].value;` is wrong.... You can not check multiple things at once.... And it is looking for variables....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should really be using the `onSubmit` handler**

As people already pointed at on the comments, there is already a built-in way to verify if all required fields are filled before submitting the form, which is quite more elegant to use. In order to do that, all you need to do is using the `onSubmit` handler instead of `onClick`:

```
<input type="submit" class="contact-form-btn" onClick="return submitForm()" value="Send">
```

This way, you don't write any code to verify if the user filled all the field properly.

**If you still want to use javascript:**

The code you wrote does not work as expected because there is not a var called `yname` on your space. If you really want to do this check via javascript, you could do something like this:

```
var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];
if (!myForm["yname"].value || myForm["email"].value || myForm["ymessage"].value) {
  alert("Please complete form.");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: For your answer to be correct, you have to do `[field].value`, so it work. Because, for example, using `myForm.email` refers to the `email` field. All objects in JavaScript are `truthy` (including `new Boolean(false)`).

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed onClick to the onSubmit handler and replaced the if else statement with just the alert and form reset. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly accessing the value. Please take a look at my answer below:

```js
document.querySelector('form[name="myForm"]').onsubmit = ev => {
  let yName = document.querySelector('input[name="yname"]').value;
  if (yName) {
    alert("Your message has been sent.");
  } else {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert("Please complete form.");
  }
};
```

```html
<form name="myForm" class="contact-form" action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <input type="text" name="yname" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
  <input type="email" name="yemail" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your Email" required>
  <textarea class="contact-form-text" name="ymessage" placeholder="Your 
Message" required></textarea>
  <input type="reset" class="contact-form-btn-reset" value="Reset">
  <input type="submit" class="contact-form-btn" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: And why `document.querySelector('form[name="myForm"]')` when setting an `id` and using `document.getElementById()` is easier? Also, why throw ES6 syntax on someone who's clearly beginning with Javascript? Just wondering.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `document.querySelector('form[name="myForm"]')` is so OP could work with the JS above without modifying any HTML. ES6 syntax is in my opinion cleaner and easier to read, plus it adds exposure to people unfamiliar with it (if asked, I would give a pre-ES6 example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas <-- the fact that this question has, currently, 171788 views demonstrates that it isn't that clear. And yes, but that introduces something new and confusing: CSS selectors. I think it is better to start by going over the simple first, then introduce the more "advanced". With this, I'm not saying your answer is bad or wrong: it is mostly right on the point.

Comment: That's a fair point, I guess I should be making my answers more clear, and if I use ES6 syntax I should be better explaining what goes on if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When your `input` is blank, the web browser is preventing the form submission because of the `required` attribute.  If you remove it, things should work how you expect.  I would encourage you go use the `required` attribute and HTML form validation.  It's much simpler that writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is that the code stops executing at

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"][yname][yemail][ymessage].value
```

This is because, yname, yemail, and ymessage are undeclared variables.

You can access an object using this notation, but the keys sent to the [] operator must be a valid string.

I think what you might want to do is

```
var name = document.forms["myForm"]["yname"].value
var email = document.forms["myForm"]["yemail"].value
var message = document.forms["myForm"]["ymessage"].value
```

Also one more thing, inputs on your form should have an id="yname", id="yemail" and so forth.

Example:

```
<input type="email" name="yemail" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your Email" required id="yemail">
```

Edit: Using name attributes are valid, but as i said above, the code stops executing upon the first use of yname, this is because the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem here is the `required` attribute.  And using a `name` attributes are absolutely valid, it's just fallen out of fashion.

Comment: Sure, i can agree that the using name attributes is valid, but if you look at this code, he is calling yname as a variable, which doesn't exist. The code will stop executing.