# How is the body passed to the return statement in this function

Tags: javascript, function

I have been going through a certain codebase and I came across a function definition like shown below:

```
function handleSuccess(res) {
    return (body = {}) =>
    res.status(statusCode).jsend.success({
        status: statusCode,
        success: true,
        ...body,
      })
}
```

The function is then called like this:

```
handleSuccess(res)({ message: 'message' });
```

I seem not to understand how the body({ message: 'message' }) is being passed to the return statement of the function above. I would thus appreciate any help on how this function works in Javascript.

Comment: Can you say what you believe the `=>` means in JS? Unless we have some idea of what your beliefs are about JS, it is hard to explain your confusion.

Comment: That's ES6, I understand what that means, my only problem is about how the body is passed to the return statement or just to the function since it's not defined in the function arguments

Comment: Well you are asking how the argument is passed to the return, but it is not passed to the return at all, hence my question.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough: I think the question is, how does body get assigned the object { message: 'message' }

Comment: In your example, there is a parameter `res` of function `handleSuccess`. Can you explain "how the argument to `handleSuccess` gets assigned to `res`"? If you can explain that, then you know how the value of the argument is assigned to `body`. If you cannot explain that, then that is the problem that should be attacked first. So, how is the value of the argument assigned to formal parameter `res`?

Comment: I think I got it, correct me if am wrong:
`handleSuccess` returns an unnamed function which takes the body as an optional argument. This means we can call the function like `handleSuccess(res)()` or `handleSuccess(res)(optional_argument_for_the_returned function)`. Here the optional argument will be passed to the returned function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194684/discussion-between-meshack-mbuvi-and-eric-lippert).

Answer (score 5):

`handleSuccess` creates and returns a function (using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax). The call to it is being run (as a result of the `(res)` after it), and then the funtion it returns is being called with the object created by the object initializer.

```
//  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---------------------------- creates the function
    handleSuccess(res)({ message: 'message' });
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --- calls the function
```

The call to it could also be written like this, which might be clearer:

```
const handler = handleSuccess(res);
handler({ message: 'message' });
```

More:

- [What's the meaning of “=>” (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)