# Angularfire v6 undefined AngularFireStore in Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

My login component logs the user in successfully, but then I'd like to create a document for this user in FireStore.

I keep getting an issue loading the AngularFirestore `afs` in this case.

```
zone-evergreen.js:659 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'afs' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'afs' of undefined
    at onLoginFulfiled (login.component.ts:32)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:365)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:851
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
```

Here is my login component code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginRequest } from './loginRequest';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

export interface Item { uid: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginRequest: LoginRequest = { password: '', login: ''};
  constructor(public fireAuth: AngularFireAuth, public afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login(): void {
    console.log(this.loginRequest);
    this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginRequest.login, this.loginRequest.password)
      .then(this.onLoginFulfiled, this.onLoginRejected);
  }

  onLoginFulfiled(credential: auth.UserCredential): void {
    console.log('Fulfilled: ' + credential);
    const uid = credential.user.uid;
    const userDocument = this.afs.doc<Item>(`system-users/${uid}`);
    userDocument.update({uid});
  }

  onLoginRejected(reason: any): void {
    console.log('Rejected: ' + reason);
  }
}
```

Also my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAnalyticsModule } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
.then(this.onLoginFulfiled, this.onLoginRejected);
```

with

```
.then(() => this.onLoginFulfiled(), () => this.onLoginRejected());
```

Comment: Ugh - crazy this worked.  Can you help me understand why this worked!?  I'm newer to angular, also  I'd like to update question to be more exact.

Comment: login(): void {
    this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginRequest.login, this.loginRequest.password)
      .then(
        (credential) => this.onLoginFulfiled(credential),
        (reason: any) => this.onLoginRejected(reason)
      );
  }

Comment: Here's how it looked exactly, I ran into a different issue, but one with my firestore setup which can work through now.

Comment: @EvanAnger I don't think this is Angular-related. It's about how `this` works in functions. With `=>`, the `this` is your `LoginComponent`, which has the `afs` property. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/6002078

Comment: @EvanAnger an alternative would be `this.onLoginFulfiled.bind(this)`, which makes the `this` inside the function to be the `this` from the context you use `bind()` at (which is the `LoginComponent`.

Comment: OK - I should have said... I'm new not just to Angular but JS/TS/etc. haha.  Thanks for the link and suggestion.  I'm back rolling on this fun journey here.