# Can someone explain one line of this javascript codes for me? Thanks

Tags: javascript

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
  let nums = Array.from({ length: num + 1 })
    .map((_, i) => i)
    .slice(2);
  for (let n in nums) {
    nums = nums.filter(val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0);
  }
  return nums.reduce((prevSum, cur) => prevSum + cur);
}
```

That is a simple function for adding prime numbers till `num`.
I am new to javascript and this following line really confuses me.

```
nums = nums.filter(val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0)
```

I know what the filter function does. But I am confused by the statement inside the parentheses.
Can someone explain a little bit? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: What part of it is unclear? In words: *filter `nums`, leaving only those which are equal to `nums[n]` or whose remainder when divided by `nums[n]` isn't zero.*

Comment: Its just the implementation of this [trial division primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division)

Answer (score 2):

```js
nums = nums.filter(val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0)
```

1. Nums is an Array
2. A higher Order Function called Filter is getting used on it, you can read more on `filter` here at mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
3. if the current value in the iteration which is `Val` is equal to the `nums[n]` or it's not divided completely by `nums[n]` then it will get returned otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key thing you need to understand is that the line in question must be considered in the context of the for statement that precedes it.

```
for (let n in nums) {
    nums = nums.filter(val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0);
  }
```

At first glance, it may look like "val == nums[n]" will always be true.  Let's see why that is not the case.

There are many things to evaluate every time the filter method's function runs:

a) The contents of nums

b) The value of n

c) The value of nums[n]

d) The value of val

e) The value of "val == nums[n]"

f) The value of "val % nums[n] != 0"

These things need to be evaluated for every call in the .filter function.

Let's see what that looks like during the first call in the filter function.  During this first call:

a) The contents of nums is {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

b) The value of n is 0

c) The value of nums[n] is nums[0], which is 2

d) The value of val is 2

e) The value of "val == nums[n}]" becomes "2 == 2", which is TRUE

f) The value of "val % num[n] !=0" becomes FALSE

So, this first element will be kept in nums because "val == nums[n}]" is TRUE.

Next, filter will evaluate the above for val = 3 and so on.

Once the filter is through with n=0, it will proceed with the n=1.

Remember that nums is being modified during each run of .filter.

Answer (score 0):

`nums = nums.filter(val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0)`

Lets start at the beginning.
the line is saying that `nums = nums` (that value).

You can tell that this line is not the first one where `nums` is used because the line doesn't begin with `var`, `const`, `let`...

That is why you can use `nums` when defining it. You are using `nums`' previous value inside it's new value.

`filter()` creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function).

You can read fully about `.filter()` using the links below.

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

If the current value in the iteration `val  => ...`, `val` is either equal to the `nums[n]` or (which is represented by `||`) isn't completely divided by `nums[n]` so it doesn't equal `0` (this is represented by `val % nums[n] != 0`) that it will get returned otherwise.

I hope this solves your problem and helps you better understand that line of code!

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = nums.filter(val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0)
```

**1. update the value of `nums**

reassign the value of `nums` to a new array which will contain items from the initial value of `nums` array when the callback of the `filter` function return true.

> nums = nums.filter(val => callback)

**2. The callback**

```
val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0
```

the above line is equivalent to

```
function (val) {
    return val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] !=0;
}
```

as this line if formed inside of a *LOOP*

```js
// considere firstly `nums` = [2,4,5,7,8]
let nums = [2,4,5,7,8];


for(let n in nums) {
    nums = nums.filter((val) => {
      console.log(`for n = ${n} ==> .filter is called with val = ${val}`);
      console.log(`So val === nums[n] return ${val == nums[n]}`);
      return val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0;
    });
    console.log(`==================================`);
}

console.log(nums);
```

I will explain only when the for loop is execute the first time

So let consider

```
let nums = [2,4,5,7,8];
```

When the for loop is executed for the first time the variable `n` which is the **index** of the **FOR LOOP**, `n` = `0` and `val` = `2` the callback check this line `val => val == nums[n] || val % nums[n] != 0` by value it equal to

```
return 2 == nums[0] || 2 % nums[0] != 0;
```

Equal to

```
return 2 == 2 || 2 % 2 != 0
```

Or

```
return true || false != 0 // this return true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am still confusing. Isn't val == nums[n] always true?

Comment: No, when the filter is executed, It's some king of loop which is executed for each element in the array. So in the loop the callback to `.filter` will be call respectively when `n` = `0`. with val equal `2`, `4`, `5`, `7`, `8`. With that `val== nums[n]` will be false when the **filter callback** for `n=0` is passed **4**, **5**, **7**, **8**. As It will check `2==4`, `2==5`, `2==7` and `2==8` which will always be false. That is the reason why for **`n=0`** **nums** Array will contains only `2` like this `[2]`

Comment: rerun the above code snippet you'll see how many the filter is call and different value with which it's called

Comment: Can you translate val == nums[n] into human language? What values does the author want to filter out? Thank you.