# Javascript add universal selector CSS rule via click on element - OR update universal selector rule to have class name

Tags: jquery, css, debugging

Debugging a UI on mobile devices is made easier if we can highlight the elements which cause horizontal scrolling - this can be done easily enough with the following line of CSS, which uses the universal selector:

```
* { border: 1px solid #f00 !important; }
```

Works nice, but to turn it on and off we need to recompile sass, or step outside of our defined process... or find a nice JS solution.

We have a handy BootStrap breakpoint viewer and it makes sense to add a click action to this to apply the CSS rule - On / Off, so we can save some time and give a good UX to the UI developers..

So, first goes are not working well, we can't use `addClass` and then `removeClass` as the selector is not named..

Also, we've tried a few variants of the following to apply to css rule globally, but they are not working yet:

```
// click to add debug borders ##
jQuery('#bs_helper').click(function(e){

    // console.log( 'Clicked BS..' );
    jQuery( document ).find("*").css( "border", "1px solid #f00 !important" );

});
```

Also, did not work with:

```
jQuery( "*" ).css( "border", "1px solid #f00 !important" );
```

Any hints? We need a single click to add and another to remove the rule.

Thanks!

**UPDATE** - this works, but perhaps there is a better way?

```
var $bs_helper_css = false;

// click to add debug borders ##
jQuery('#bs_helper').click(function(e){

    if( ! $bs_helper_css ) {

        var html = "<style id='bs_helper_css'>* { border: 1px solid #f00 !important; }</style>";
        console.log( 'Add: '+html );
        jQuery('body').append(html); 

        // tracker ##
        $bs_helper_css = true;

    } else {

        console.log( 'Remove CSS' );
        jQuery('#bs_helper_css').remove();

        // tracker ##
        $bs_helper_css = false;

    }

    return true;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add/remove a class on `body`

```
body.debug * { border: 1px dashed pink; }
```

for a bonus, you can also exclude items (such as your debug button) if needed:

```js
$("#debug").click(function() { $("body").toggleClass("debug"); });
```

```css
body.debug :not(.nodebug) { border: 1px dashed pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>basic element</div>
<div><div>nested element</div></div>
<hr class='nodebug' />
<button type='button' id='debug' class='nodebug'>debug</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent! What is this syntax? "... => ..." as in $("#debug").click(() => $("body").toggleClass("debug")); - looks like pseudo code, but works without error?

Comment: It's ES6, same as `.click(function() { $("body")...` only you can't use `this` inside `=>`.  Doesn't work in IE11 but works in modern browsers

Comment: In this case, it's a debugging tool, so we probably need it to work better in IE than anywhere else ;)

Comment: Updated to pre-ES6 anonymous function.  Worth a read (not a duplicate of the question, just for this syntax) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900924/2181514