# Vue.js - Access data variable from callback function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the Deezer Javascript SDK to play an audio track.

On their documentation there is a bunch of events defined such as `player_loaded`, `player_paused`, `track_end`, etc.

They also show how subscribe to an event:

```
// Callback function is called when the current player has resumed or started playing
DZ.Event.subscribe('player_play', function(evt_name){
    console.log("Player is playing");
});
 
// Callback function is called when the currently playing track has changed
DZ.Event.subscribe('current_track', function(track, evt_name){
    console.log("Currently playing track", track);
});
 
// Callback function is called when the volume level of the current player has changed
DZ.Event.subscribe('volume_changed', function(args, evt_name){
    console.log("The current volume level is " + args);
});
```

This works fine so far.

I was wondering if it is possible to **access a variable from within the inner function**:

```
DZ.Event.subscribe("track_end", function (evt_name) {
            console.log("event fired 1");
            //trying to access this bool var that is defined in data
            this.isDeezerPlaying = false;
});
```

This is not working. I would have to pass in `this` as a parameter to the callback function in order to access my local variable `isDeezerPlaying`. But it is not me calling this function and passing the parameters but it is the SDK who does that somewhere under the hud.

So is there still a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. You either use arrow functions

```
DZ.Event.subscribe("track_end", (evt_name) => {
            console.log("event fired 1");
            //trying to access this bool var that is defined in data
            this.isDeezerPlaying = false;
});
```

or you bind it:

```
DZ.Event.subscribe("track_end", function (evt_name) {
            console.log("event fired 1");
            //trying to access this bool var that is defined in data
            this.isDeezerPlaying = false;
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

try with below code:

```
const vm = this;
DZ.Event.subscribe("track_end", function (evt_name) {
   console.log("event fired 1");
   //trying to access this bool var that is defined in data
   vm.isDeezerPlaying = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by using arrow functions :

```js
DZ.Event.subscribe("track_end", (evt_name) => {
            console.log("event fired 1");
            this.isDeezerPlaying = false;
});
```

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900924/5671919