# map function in react with arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know what's going on here but I m not able to understand the map function here how it's working please tell me briefly ...

what I understand here is that the map function taking each element of the testData array and calls a function "wow" obviously wow function will store the map value after this function "wow" return something so its returning  what I am confused is about the syntax here ...

```
{testData.map(wow => <Card {...wow}/>)}

const testData = [
    {name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook"},
    {name: "Sophie Alpert", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", company: "Humu"},
    {name: "Sebastian Markbåge", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/63648?v=4", company: "Facebook"},
];

const CardList = () => (
    <div>
    {testData.map(wow => <Card {...wow}/>)}
  </div>
);

class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
    const profile = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="github-profile">
          <img src={profile.avatar_url} />
        <div className="info">
          <div className="name">{profile.name}</div>
          <div className="company">{profile.company}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="header">{this.props.title}</div>
        <CardList />
        </div>
    );
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App title="The GitHub Cards App" />,
  mountNode,
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: Possibly helpful as well: [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1218980)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I understand here is that the map function taking each element of the testData array and calls a function "wow" obviously wow function will store the map value after this function "wow" return

This is close, but not quite right. `map()` takes a function, but here you use the `=>` syntax which is an anonymous function. That is, the function doesn't have a name. `wow` here is the name of the single argument to the function, not the name of the function.

`map()` passes each element of `testData()` into this anonymous function. Then that function returns something. This return value is used as the element in a new array that is eventually returned by `map()`.

Answer (score 2):

map takes this function `A => B`, so basically the function is made by all that's enclosed the parenthesis.
If look at my definition, A is the input argument and B is the output,which translates in wow = A and <Card {...wow} /> as B

Answer (score 2):

There's several short-hand syntaxes here so maybe the clearest thing would be to write the function in long form and then re-shorten it with an explanation at each step.

**Long form:**

```
{testData.map((wow) => {
  return <Card name={wow.name} avatar_url={wow.avatar_url} company={wow.company} />
})}
```

Let's start by adding the [spread syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) of `wow`. When you want to pass each of an object's values as props to a component, you can do so like this: `<Comp {...obj}/>`.

This leaves us with a slightly shorter version that's still equivalent to the original's meaning:

```js
{testData.map((wow) => {
  return <Card {...wow} />
})}
```

Next we have an [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which means everything within the function body should be returned. This allows you to leave off the wrapping braces `{}` and drop the `return` keyword.

```js
{testData.map((wow) => <Card {...wow} />)}
```

Finally, for single argument arrow functions, you may leave off the parenthesis in the function declaration:

```js
{testData.map(wow => <Card {...wow} />)}
```

**To summarize:**

`wow` is not the name of a function, but a parameter to an inline arrow function that takes advantage of several short-hand syntaxes.

`map` returns an instance of `Card` for each element in the array. Each iteration of the array the component is given all the values of the `wow` object as props.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, the wow is an element for the array so the map is going to get each element in the testData.

The map is going to return 3 elements:

1º

```
{name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook"},
```

2º

```
{name: "Sophie Alpert", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", company: "Humu"},
```

3º

```
{name: "Sebastian Markbåge", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/63648?v=4", company: "Facebook"},
```

But in that case will be returned in the Card component