# Confused about this particular JavaScript way of expressing a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, arrow-functions

I know there are different ways of **declaring a function** (or **expressing** it), however, I haven't seen/used anything like this before (given, I am a "newbie" in the field). Can someone, please, explain how this particular function declaration works and when it is used? Can't wrap my head around that **":"** following function name!

```
const formSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<IFormInputs> = () => {}
```

*(Not sure if it has anything to do with typescript)*

```
import './App.css';
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form'

type IFormInputs = {
  email: string,
  password: string
}

const formSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<IFormInputs> = (data: IFormInputs) => {
  console.log('the form data is', data);
}


const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: {errors}} = useForm<IFormInputs>()

  console.log(errors, 'this is an error explanation');
  console.log(watch('email'), 'watch the email variable');

  return (
    <div style={{padding: '2rem', border: '1px black solid'}}>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmitHandler)}>
      <input defaultValue='example.test.@gmail.com' {...register('email')}/>
      <br />
      {errors.password && <span>This field is required</span>}
      <br />
      <input {...register('password', { required: true })}/>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
  )
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) But yes, the `: SubmitHandler<IFormInputs>` part is TypeScript.

Comment: @SiddharthS. - No, it's not the function's return type. It's the **type** of the variable (constant), a function type.

Comment: Related: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22173438/157247) describing the various kinds of function declarations and function expressions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```typescript
const formSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<IFormInputs> = (data: IFormInputs) => {
  console.log('the form data is', data);
}
```

is TypeScript code that says the type of the `formSubmitHandler` constant is `SubmitHandler<IFormInputs>`, which is a type (`SubmitHandler`) with a generic type argument (`IFormInputs`). `SubmitHandler` is presumably a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types) defining a function type, probably something like this:

```typescript
type SubmitHandler<DataType> = (data: DataType) => void;
```

The *value* assigned to that constant is an [arrow function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) accepting a single `data` parameter of the type `IFormInputs`.

For what it's worth, here's the equivalent JavaScript code (in this case, that's just removing the type annotations):

```js
const formSubmitHandler = (data) => {
  console.log('the form data is', data);
}
```

*(In both cases, the code is relying on Automatic Semicolon Insertion because there should be a `;` at the end of the assignment statement [just after the closing `}` of the function body]. Given that the author included the `;` on the `console.log`, the missing `;` on the assignment is probably a typo/misunderstanding, not an intentional decision to use ASI.)*

Comment: Thank you very much @T.J.Crowder!! That makes it much clearer!!

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function (aka fat arrow function ()=>{}) is similar in essence to lambda functions of other languages. It does not have .this value.

They are quick ways to return computed values without all the overhead of named functions or methods.

If you would like to know more, check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Fireship does a really good job of differentiating different functions and their purposes [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gigtS_5KOqo).

With Typescript you can declare the assigned variable name of the anonymous function as an arrow function. Say we have a compute function that adds to values passed into the function:

Javascript:

```
const add = (a, b) =>{
  return a+b
}
```

Typescript

```
const add = (a:number, b:number) =>{
  return a+b
}
```

Now add does not have a static type and may be inferred, however, if you need strict type declarations (preferable) you need to define a type for add as a function which would look like (parameters)=> return type:

```
type Add = (a: number, b: number) => number;

const add: Add = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

Comment: Appreciate your detailed explanation @mpmcintyre !!