# How to call a JavaScript function inside itself with this()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My following code gives the error message `this is not a function` (see code-snippet line 8). How do I correctly call it then?

```js
((e) => {
  if(e.children == null || e.children.length == 0) return;
  e = e.children;
        
  $(e).each( (i, o) => {
    console.log(o);
    this(o);
  })

})(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you'll have to give the function a name

Comment: Which function are you expecting to be `this`? They're both _arrow_ functions, for one thing, which don't have their own `this`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/3001761.

Comment: Why do you have that odd mix of vanilla JS and jQuery?