# Arrow function and Promises in Lightning Web Components

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

I have seen many examples of Promises but not able to understand meaning of
"`xyz(()=>{`"
in codes. Sometimes there are two equal signs in same line. Please help me understand. Also, along with that please drop a link from where I can easily learn javascript for LWC.

*Thanks!*

Comment: "Sometimes there are two equal signs in same line." Can you provide an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: @rb612 check this video timeframe https://youtu.be/h33Srr5J9nY?t=129

Answer (score 0):

() => { } is An arrow function expression whitch is a compact alternative to a traditional function expression. where () contains params and {} contains the execution code.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // code here
    });
```

above code is same as

```
new Promise(function () {
      // code here
});
```

read this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving from "old school" JavaScript or Aura components to LWC this trailhead might help: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/learn-to-work-with-javascript

It'll explain that it's not really LWC that comes up with all these new toys, any decent ES6 (JavaScript spec from 2015 onwards) tutorial should help you.

- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/modern-javascript-development/understand-javascript-functions (arrow functions)
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/modern-javascript-development/write-asynchronous-javascript (promises)
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/javascript-essentials-salesforce-developers/async-js (both really)

I've also found the [MDN resource for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to be pretty cool. The code blocks go step by step like some math proof.